# read a JSON object in java

Tags: java, json, jsp

How can we read a JSON object in a JSP, Servlet or in any other Java program?

Comment: can we use gson object for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend using [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) for this. It has the advantage that it supports generics very well and it is also performant. I've posted a `Gson#fromJson()` example before here: [Converting JSON to Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688099/converting-json-to-java/1688182#1688182)

Answer (score 5):

With the [json](http://json.org/java/) library, there is a JAR of it located [here](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/org/json/json/20090211/json-20090211.jar). Also, based upon [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library/338933#338933), you might want to look at [JSON-lib](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 3):

[JSON.org](http://www.json.org/java/index.html) has a lot of good information on reading JSON in Java (and other languages as well).  They provide a good reference implementation that many other libraries use.

Comment: That's a good page -- not sure the ref impl is all that great (almost all alternatives from the page are better IMO), but it's good it has been available for years now, and has encourages others to implement better alternatives. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Using a library such as the one described at: http://www.json.org/java/

Looking at the description of [gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/), it certainly looks like it would do the job as well.