# How to read complex JSON string which contains escape characters and coordinate values

Tags: java, json

How to read this complex JSON string in JAVA?

```
  "graphSpace": "[[{\"rectangle\":\"{\\n  \\\"minX\\\": 0.0,\\n  \\\"minY\\\": 0.0,\\n  \\\"maxX\\\": 0.0,\\n  \\\"maxY\\\": 0.0\\n}\",\"contents\":\"\",\"rights\":\"[]\",\"lefts\":\"[]\",\"tops\":\"[]\",\"downs\":\"[]\",\"annotation\":\"{\\n  \\\"id\\\": 504,\\n  \\\"type\\\": \\\"line\\\"\\n}\"},{\"rectangle\":\"{\\n  \\\"minX\\\": 0.0,\\n  \\\"minY\\\": 0.0,\\n  \\\"maxX\\\": 0.0,\\n  \\\"maxY\\\": 0.0\\n}\",\"contents\":\"\",\"rights\":\"[]\",\"lefts\":\"[{\\\"id\\\":504}]\",\"tops\":\"[{\\\"id\\\":504}]\",\"downs\":\"[]\",\"annotation\":\"{\\n  \\\"id\\\": 242,\\n  \\\"type\\\": \\\"line\\\"\\n}\"}],[{\"rectangle\":\"{\\n  \\\"minX\\\": 430.0,\\n  \\\"minY\\\": 146.0,\\n  \\\"maxX\\\": 940.0,\\n  \\\"maxY\\\": 197.0\\n}\",\"contents\":\"Center Hoist Co.\",\"rights\":\"[{\\\"id\\\":36},{\\\"id\\\":38},{\\\"id\\\":52},{\\\"id\\\":57}]\",\"lefts\":\"[]\",\"tops\":\"[{\\\"id\\\":504}]\",\"downs\":\"[{\\\"id\\\":13},{\\\"id\\\":16},{\\\"id\\\":19},{\\\"id\\\":22},{\\\"id\\\":25},{\\\"id\\\":27},{\\\"id\\\":29},{\\\"id\\\":96},{\\\"id\\\":99},{\\\"id\\\":101},{\\\"id\\\":110},{\\\"id\\\":115},{\\\"id\\\":141},{\\\"id\\\":136},{\\\"id\\\":167},{\\\"id\\\":188},{\\\"id\\\":204},{\\\"id\\\":235},{\\\"id\\\":237},{\\\"id\\\":291},{\\\"id\\\":293},{\\\"id\\\":344},{\\\"id\\\":346},{\\\"id\\\":397},{\\\"id\\\":399},{\\\"id\\\":558},{\\\"id\\\":626}]\",\"annotation\":\"{\\n  \\\"id\\\": 10,\\n  \\\"type\\\": \\\"line\\\"\\n}\"},{\"rectangle\":\"{\\n  \\\"minX\\\": 1285.0,\\n  \\\"minY\\\": 143.0,\\n  \\\"maxX\\\": 1532.0,\\n  \\\"maxY\\\": 195.0\\n}\",\"contents\":\"4sO^ Employee\",\"rights\":\"[{\\\"id\\\":52},{\\\"id\\\":57}]\",\"lefts\":\"[{\\\"id\\\":10}]\",\"tops\":\"[{\\\"id\\\":504}]\",\"downs\":\"[{\\\"id\\\":38},{\\\"id\\\":41},{\\\"id\\\":43},{\\\"id\\\":93},{\\\"id\\\":96},{\\\"id\\\":99},{\\\"id\\\":101},{\\\"id\\\":120},{\\\"id\\\":146},{\\\"id\\\":172},{\\\"id\\\":193},{\\\"id\\\":209},{\\\"id\\\":214},{\\\"id\\\":254},{\\\"id\\\":310},{\\\"id\\\":363},{\\\"id\\\":416},{\\\"id\\\":572},{\\\"id\\\":604},{\\\"id\\\":626}]\",\"annotation\":\"{\\n  \\\"id\\\": 36,\\n  \\\"type\\\": \\\"line\\\"\\n}\"},{\"rectangle\":\"{\\n  \\\"minX\\\": 1394.0,\\n  \\\"minY\\\": 194.0,\\n  \\\"maxX\\\": 1487.0,\\n  \\\"maxY\\\": 221.0\\n}\",\"contents\":\"Owned\",\"rights\":\"[{\\\"id\\\":36}]\",\"lefts\":\"[{\\\"id\\\":36},{\\\"id\\\":13},{\\\"id\\\":10}]\",\"tops\":\"[{\\\"id\\\":10},{\\\"id\\\":36},{\\\"id\\\":504}]\",\"downs\":\"[{\\\"id\\\":41},{\\\"id\\\":43},{\\\"id\\\":93},{\\\"id\\\":96},{\\\"id\\\":99},{\\\"id\\\":101},{\\\"id\\\":120},{\\\"id\\\":146},{\\\"id\\\":172},{\\\"id\\\":193},{\\\"id\\\":214},{\\\"id\\\":626}]\",\"annotation\":\"{\\n  \\\"id\\\": 38,\\n  \\\"type\\\": \\\"line\\\"\\n}\"},{\"rectangle\":\"{\\n  \\\"minX\\\": 1833.0,\\n  \\\"minY\\\": 163.0,\\n  \\\"maxX\\\": 1990.0,\\n  \\\"maxY\\\": 193.0\\n}\",\"contents\":\"Invoice #\",\"rights\":\"[{\\\"id\\\":57}]\",\"lefts\":\"[{\\\"id\\\":36},{\\\"id\\\":10}]\",\"tops\":\"[{\\\"id\\\":10},{\\\"id\\\":36},{\\\"id\\\":504}]\",\"downs\":\"[{\\\"id\\\":63},{\\\"id\\\":74},{\\\"id\\\":86},{\\\"id\\\":93},{\\\"id\\\":96},{\\\"id\\\":99},{\\\"id\\\":125},{\\\"id\\\":151},{\\\"id\\\":198},{\\\"id\\\":224},{\\\"id\\\":548},{\\\"id\\\":577},{\\\"id\\\":614},{\\\"id\\\":626}]\",\"annotation\":\"{\\n  \\\"id\\\": 52,\\n  \\\"type\\\": \\\"line\\\"\\n}\"},{\"rectangle\":\"{\\n  \\\"minX\\\": 2226.0,\\n  \\\"minY\\\": 159.0,\\n  \\\"maxX\\\": 2411.0,\\n  \\\"maxY\\\": 192.0\\n}\",\"contents\":\"00760287\",\"rights\":\"[]\",\"lefts\":\"[{\\\"id\\\":52},{\\\"id\\\":36},{\\\"id\\\":10}]\",\"tops\":\"[{\\\"id\\\":10},{\\\"id\\\":36},{\\\"id\\\":504}]\",\"downs\":\"[{\\\"id\\\":68},{\\\"id\\\":79},{\\\"id\\\":86},{\\\"id\\\":130},{\\\"id\\\":156},{\\\"id\\\":198},{\\\"id\\\":229},{\\\"id\\\":282},{\\\"id\\\":338},{\\\"id\\\":391},{\\\"id\\\":444},{\\\"id\\\":582},{\\\"id\\\":619},{\\\"id\\\":626}]\",\"annotation\":\"{\\n  \\\"id\\\": 57,\\n  \\\"type\\\": \\\"line\\\"\\n}\"}],[{\"rectangle\":\"{\\n  \\\"minX\\\": 438.0,\\n  \\\"minY\\\": 209.0,\\n  \\\"maxX\\\": 837.0,\\n  \\\"maxY\\\": 245.0\\n}\",\"contents\":\"Hydraulic Equipment\",\"rights\":\"[{\\\"id\\\":38}]\",\"lefts\":\"[]\",\"tops\":\"[{\\\"id\\\":10},{\\\"id\\\":504}]\",\"downs\":\"[{\\\"id\\\":16},{\\\"id\\\":19},{\\\"id\\\":22},{\\\"id\\\":25},{\\\"id\\\":27},{\\\"id\\\":29},{\\\"id\\\":96},{\\\"id\\\":99},{\\\"id\\\":101},{\\\"id\\\":110},{\\\"id\\\":115},{\\\"id\\\":141},{\\\"id\\\":136},{\\\"id\\\":167},{\\\"id\\\":188},{\\\"id\\\":204},{\\\"id\\\":235},{\\\"id\\\":237},{\\\"id\\\":291},{\\\"id\\\":293},{\\\"id\\\":344},{\\\"id\\\":346},{\\\"id\\\":397},{\\\"id\\\":399},{\\\"id\\\":558},{\\\"id\\\":626}]\",\"annotation\":\"{\\n  \\\"id\\\": 13,\\n  \\\"type\\\": \\\"line\\\"\\n}\"}],[{\"rectangle\":\"{\\n  \\\"minX\\\": 441.0,\\n  \\\"minY\\\": 261.0,\\n  \\\"maxX\\\": 724.0,\\n  \\\"maxY\\\": 289.0\\n}\",\"contents\":\"4782 Bourne Dr.\",\"rights\":\"[{\\\"id\\\":43},{\\\"id\\\":41},{\\\"id\\\":63},{\\\"id\\\":68}]\",\"lefts\":\"[]\",\"tops\":\"[{\\\"id\\\":13},{\\\"id\\\":10},{\\\"id\\\":504}]\",\"downs\":\"[{\\\"id\\\":19},{\\\"id\\\":22},{\\\"id\\\":25},{\\\"id\\\":27},{\\\"id\\\":29},{\\\"id\\\":96},{\\\"id\\\":99},{\\\"id\\\":101},{\\\"id\\\":110},{\\\"id\\\":115},{\\\"id\\\":141},{\\\"id\\\":136},{\\\"id\\\":167},{\\\"id\\\":188},{\\\"id\\\":204},{\\\"id\\\":235},{\\\"id\\\":237},{\\\"id\\\":291},{\\\"id\\\":293},{\\\"id\\\":344},{\\\"id\\\":346},{\\\"id\\\":397},{\\\"id\\\":399},{\\\"id\\\":558},{\\\"id\\\":626}]\",\"annotation\":\"{\\n  \\\"id\\\": 16,\\n  \\\"type\\\": \\\"line\\\"\\n}\"},{\"rectangle\":\"{\\n  \\\"minX\\\": 1296.0,\\n  \\\"minY\\\": 284.0,\\n  \\\"maxX\\\": 1539.0,\\n  \\\"maxY\\\": 313.0\\n}\",\"contents\":\"Registered\",\"rights\":\"[{\\\"id\\\":63}
```

This is not even complete. But I want to read only needed things like ***cenetr hoist*** based on this rectangle and coordinate values. Any idea how to parse this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below example can be used:

```
 JsonObject obj= gson.fromJson(DATA,JsonObject.class);
```

In this DATA is the complex Json string and JsonObject is the class which contains Variable to match the jspn string.

Variable names are case sensitive means it should match with json elements.

In your case Jsonobject.java will contain below variables:

```
Array of graphSpace

rectangle
contents etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Probable you should look in to stackexchange forum:

[Converting JSON to Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688099/converting-json-to-java/1688182#1688182)

[read a JSON object in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798038/read-a-json-object-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Use a [JSON parser](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java). JSON is too complex to easily parse correctly in an ad-hoc way.