# Communication between JSP and Servlet?

Tags: xml, jsp, servlets

I have a jsp page that communicate with a servlet back end. Up until now, the way I communicate with that servlet is via .getJSON() which is a JQuery method. This work great if the data I want to send back is in the form of {key:value}. However, now I need to send a bit more data then that. The largest table in my database, contain roughly eleven attributes, and the number of row is about 20-40. It is not big, but not small to send table via JSON. I am think about XML, and I wonder if any one can shed me some light. Sample codes would be appreciated, link to tutorial, article would be awesome as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just have the data in a collection or map of fullworthy Javabeans and make use of [Google Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to convert it to JSON without any pains. JSON is more compact than XML and much easier to process in JavaScript (it's also the **JavaScript** Object Notation).

All you basically need to do with help of Gson is the following:

```
List<Data> list = dataDAO.list();
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.getWriter().write(new Gson().toJson(list));
```

That's all. I've answered this several times before with examples: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900711/handling-servlet-output-in-ajax), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892152/json-js-to-java-and-vice-versa-and-other-languages), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203269/loading-alternative-content-via-tabs-and-jquery-and-jsp), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938198/how-to-integrate-jquery-calendar-with-jsp) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263996/populating-child-dropdownlists-in-jsp-servlet).