# ajax call with java action in jsp (J2EE)

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I am trying to make a login page in java J2EE. Actually, I succed in making a jsp page, called `login.jsp`, an ActionSupport class called `LoginAction`. In my jsp I've created some text area, password area and submit, allowing me to send informations entered in those areas and get them in my action. This works fine.
My problem is that I don't succed in using another function than `execute`. In my action I have several other functions and I can't call them in my ajax function :

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
      $(function() {
        $('#submit').click(function() {
            var login=$("#login").val();
            var password=$("#password").val();
          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'login.action/test', // -> here it fails.............
            data: { login: login, password: password },
            success: function() {
              alert('YEAH'); },
            error: function() {
              alert('Request failed'); }
          });    
        });  
      });
</script>
```

What should I put in `url` area, if I want for example to call `test` function in my LoginAction class? (I've done a `test.jsp` page, it doesn't change anything...)

Comment: [Possible Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477782/ajax-and-jsp-integration)

Comment: what is the version of struts

Answer (score 0):

OK I found the answer. So here it is : 
It's called "dynamic method invocation" (with wildcard method), and you can find the doc here :
http://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/docs/action-configuration.html#ActionConfiguration-WildcardMethod

Answer (score 0):

It is very important to use last struts2 release to avoid critical security bugs while using wildcard method - see https://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/s2-015.html for details.

Answer (score -1):

use "function nametest()" instead of "function()"

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer. I tried to put the name of the function in my java class next to function at the 4 places where "function" is written, but it didn't changed anything...

Comment: Or I didn't understand? `function` is written 4 times, what "function" may I change?

Comment: Maybe It's a struts parameter?