# Convert array php to java

Tags: java, php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am developing an app that has java files and php files. The java files call to the php files, these execute queries in the ddbb and return the result as an array php, but printing it in the screen. I take this in java like an string, and I have to convert it to and array or collection, but I have no idea how to do it.

An example of the result that php prints is:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [0] => 1
        [name] => pepe
        [1] => pepe
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [0] => 2
        [name] => antoñito
        [1] => antoñito
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [0] => 3
        [name] => loló
        [1] => loló
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4
        [0] => 4
        [name] => ñoño
        [1] => ñoño
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [id] => 5
        [0] => 5
        [name] => Antoñito
        [1] => Antoñito
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [id] => 7
        [0] => 7
        [name] => José
        [1] => José
    )

)
```

If I use json_encode($the_array) this is the result:

```
[{"id":"1","0":"1","name":"pepe","1":"pepe"},    {"id":"2","0":"2","name":"anto\u00f1ito","1":"anto\u00f1ito"},{"id":"3","0":"3","name":"lol\u00f3","1":"lol\u00f3"},{"id":"4","0":"4","name":"\u00f1o\u00f1o","1":"\u00f1o\u00f1o"},{"id":"5","0":"5","name":"Anto\u00f1ito","1":"Anto\u00f1ito"},{"id":"7","0":"7","name":"Jos\u00e9","1":"Jos\u00e9"}]
```

Thanks everyone

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: use an interchange format like xml or json.

Comment: the best idea would be to think about your design. Passing arrays AS STRING from PHP to Java. Calling PHP from Java to do database access? All of this sounds quite horrible to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should select a serialization method for your data. For e.g. XML, [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/), or JSON.

I recommend you use JSON because it's lightweight, easy to read even for humans and there are broad libraries available for both languages.

#### Encoding on the PHP side

```
$encoded = json_encode($data);
```

#### Decoding on the Java side with Jackson

```
final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
// The better way is to create a custom class with the correct format
final Map<?, ?> decoded = objectMapper.readValue(encoded, Map.class);
```

Comment: I tried that, but when I use the json_enconde I lost each strange character. It seems the utf8 doesnt work with that

Comment: @user1274103 of course it works. JSON serialization escapes non-ASCII characters, so original characters are back when you decode it.

Comment: I have update the question with the result when I apply json_encode

Comment: @user1274103 yes, as you can see special characters are encoded to escape sequences using ASCII characters. This ensures the JSON to be easily and safely transferable through many channels (SMTP, HTTP). When you try to decode it with any tool escape sequences become their former UTF-8 values (ñ, ó, é). Just try to decode it in PHP using `json_decode()`.

Answer (score 2):

Use some more standardized transport format, like JSON. PHP side has to encode the array using `json_encode()` and Java side needs some library to decode it (see relevant [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1927885/decode-json-data-in-java)).

Answer (score 1):

I think that this can be useful http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wsmashin/v1r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.sMash.doc/using/zero.php/TypeConversion.html