# Transfer Multi rows Array PHP to Array Javascript

Tags: php, arrays

I followed this topic [Convert array php to java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11097592/convert-array-php-to-java) , but it is not successful for me.
My code:

```
<script>
    var dataobject=<?php
        $returnarry=getDataArray("Select product_id, product_name, product_price from product");


    echo json_encode(returnarry);
    ?>;
    //How to convert dataobject to  an array
</script>
```

How to convert dataobject to  an array

Answer (score -1):

PHP  function to convert PHP arrays into Javascript is  json_encode() only.Note that json_encode() is available only  in PHP 5.2 and up, so please check whther you're using an older version.

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

You can see the example in same page:
Example #1 A json_encode() example

```
<?php
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}
```

For multi dimensional arrays use below one:

```
$arr = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($returnarray)) {
$arr[] = $row; 
}
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Use it in javascript as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var jArray= <?php echo json_encode($arr); ?>;

for(var i=0;i<10;i++){ // use correct limit instead of 10
    alert(jArray[i]);
 }
</script>
```

Another way to get elements is:
    alert(jArray[0].Key);

Comment: Thanks Aajan. I knew to process when array has one row. But how about multi rows when I select data from table in SQL ?. My Php is 5.5.

Comment: Thanks Aajab. How can I use it in javascript. Can I convert it to array in Java Script, could you help me.

Comment: I tested your code, I just modified a little, then it worked:  $result = $conn->query($sql);


    $arr = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $arr[] = $row;
    }
  // var_dump($arr);
    echo json_encode($arr); In alert method, I put property of object :alert (jArray[i].Product_code)

Comment: Thanks Aajan so much.