# how to send a parameter from php to blackberry/ Java mobile app

Tags: java, php, blackberry, parameters, response

I'm new to php. Can someone please guide me. I developing an app for blackberry. I want to send a boolean parameter from my php to java as a response to my java class's request. And then get that parameter at java side. How can I do that? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Simply print your response as json.

```
$myvalue = array();
$myvalue['status'] = 0;

$jsonEncodedvalue = json_encode($myvalue);

print_r($jsonEncodedvalue);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Dino Babu. Just one more thing. How can I get this value at java side ?

Comment: i m not much aware of java. this may help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1927885/decode-json-data-in-java