# Html, handling a JSON response

Tags: java, json, htmlunit

I have a page that comes back as an UnexpectedPage in HtmlUnit, the response is JSON.  Can I use HTMLUnit to parse this or will I need an additional library?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

HtmlUnit doesn't support it. It can at highest execute a JS function. You need to check beforehand if the `Content-Type` of the returned response matches `application/json` and then use the suitable tool to parse it. [Google Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) is useful in this.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
Page page = client.getPage("https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/97901.json");
WebResponse response = page.getWebResponse();
if (response.getContentType().equals("application/json")) {
    String json = response.getContentAsString();
    Map<String, String> map = new Gson().fromJson(json, new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>() {}.getType());
    System.out.println(map.get("displayName")); // Benju
}
```

If the JSON structure is known beforehand, you can even use Gson to convert it to a fullworthy Javabean. You can find an example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688099/converting-json-to-java/1688182#1688182).

Answer (score 0):

BalusC provided a good answer, but to answer the literal question, you don't really need an additional library: you can use Groovy's neat built-in JsonSlurper, e.g:

```
 def jsonSlurper = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper()
 def parsed = jsonSlurper.parseText(response.getContentAsString())
 println("Found ${parsed.TotalCount} records.");
```

to print out `1` for a response such as

```
'{"Records":[{"ID":"123","Address":"Zagreb",],"TotalCount":1}'
```