# How to get json page using httpunit

Tags: java, webclient, http-unit

I am using web client. and login successfully through web client. but when i send second  request for getting data . I got an Exception

```
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.UnexpectedPage@6d8d73`
```

but when i pass url thruogh brouser i got a data Json format.

Code:

```
webClient.getPage("http://ajax/stream/refresh-box?r=new&id=2323222&")
```

Thx in advanced

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932857/html-handling-a-json-response

Comment: would you please add a JUnit testcase to show the point of your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the which is reading different content type through web client

```
Page page = webClient.getPage(url);
System.out.println(page);
WebResponse response = page.getWebResponse();

if (response.getContentType().equals("application/json")) 
{
pagesource = response.getContentAsString();
System.out.println(pagesource);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This URL is returning an error, if I type it in the browser, check it again:
    "http://ajax/stream/refresh-box?r=new&id=2323222&"

BTW, why does it finish with & sign while there is no additional parameter?

I removed the & sign and still I get no page exception in the browser.