# What is the JSP equivalent to json_encode ( in PHP )?

Tags: java, php, json, jsp, servlets

I am trying to encode a JSP servlet into JSON.  What's the equivalent in JSP to json_encode() in PHP ?

Comment: Ton's of Java implementations listed on http://json.org/ (listed @ the bottom)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

JSP/Servlet isn't that high-level as PHP which has practically "anything built-in". In Java you've more freedom to choose from libraries. There are several JSON libraries in Java available which you can implement in your webapp, the popular ones being under each [JSON.org](http://www.json.org/java/), [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org) and [Google Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

We use here Gson to our satisfaction. It has excellent support for parameterized collections and (nested) Javabeans. It's basically as simple as follows:

```
String json = new Gson().toJson(anyObject); // anyObject = List<Bean>, Map<K, Bean>, Bean, String, etc..
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.getWriter().write(json);
```

Converting JSON to a fullworthy Javabean is also simple with Gson, see [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688099/converting-json-to-java/1688182#1688182).

Answer (score 1):

Gson is pretty cool.

Its almost the same as `json_encode`. Note that an encoded empty string in `json_encode`evaluates to `"\"\""`

In Gson it returns `""`

Answer (score 0):

There is a list of several Java libraries that handle JSON encoding at the bottom of http://json.org/ — take your pick.

Answer (score 0):

json_encode in php is similar to following package in java

dependency:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
```

code :

```
Map<Object,Object> dataArray = {some data in map}
ObjectMapper objMapper = new ObjectMapper();
String jsonString = objMapper.writeValueAsString(dataArray);
```

jsonString is if the final result like son_encode in php, which you can achieve with objectMapper class