# Alternative use of json_encode in JSP

Tags: android, jsp

I'm developing android application and I'm using jsp for mysql connection. What is the other way to use json_encode in JSP? Because it's dedicated in PHP.

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207092/what-is-the-jsp-equivalent-to-json-encode-in-php

Comment: Thanks. I already checked that and still I need to study how to use and implement that

Answer (score 0):

Try this for like json_encoded in php it will work fine

```
 <%@page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
    <%@page import="org.json.simple.JSONObject"%>
    <%
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put("name", "john");
        json.put("mobile", "999999999");
        out.print(json);
        out.flush();
    %>
```