# Reading JSON from a text file

Tags: java, json

I know of some JSON libs around and I'm currently looking into Google-JSON but all I want to achieve is something simple and I want to know what you would suggest.

I want a JSON library which will let me read a textfile that is in JSON and let me convert it into strings, int, boolean, etc. 
-- Now using Json.org/java

It can READ! BUT!!

```
import org.json.*;

public class readJ {

    public static String MapTitle;
    public static int[][] tiles;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

                       String json =
               "{"
               +"'name': 'map_one.txt',"
                +"'title': 'Map One',"
                +"'currentMap': 4,"
                +"'items': ["
                     +"{ name: 'Pickaxe', x: 5, y: 1 },"
                     +"{ name: 'Battleaxe', x: 2, y: 3 }"
                     +"],"
                +"map': [ [ 1,3,1,1,1,24,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 ],"
                    +"[ 1,3,1,1,1,24,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 ],"
                    +"[ 1,7,1,1,1,24,1,1,24,1,1,1,1 ],"
                    +"[ 1,7,1,1,7,1,1,1,24,1,1,1,1 ],"
                    +"[ 1,7,7,7,1,24,24,24,24,1,1,1,1 ],"
                    +"[ 1,1,7,1,1,24,1,24,1,1,1,1,1 ],"
                    +"[ 1,1,1,1,1,24,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 ],"
                    +"[ 1,1,3,1,1,24,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 ],"
                    +"[ 1,3,3,1,1,24,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 ]]"
+"}";
try {
JSONObject JsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
MapTitle = JsonObj.getString("title");
tiles = JsonObj.getJSONArray("map");
}catch (JSONException er) {
    er.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println(MapTitle);
System.out.println(tiles[0][1]);

    }
}
```

When compiling I get this error:

```
C:\Users\Dan\Documents\readJSON\readJ.java:32: incompatible types
found   : org.json.JSONArray
required: int[][]
tiles = JsonObj.getJSONArray("map");
                            ^
1 error

Tool completed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Probably opening a new question for each problem you had was in order. You started asking one thing and end up asking another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install [Google Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) and create those two model classes

```
public class Data {
    private String name;
    private String title;
    private int currentMap;
    private List<Item> items;
    private int[][] map;

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public String getTitle() { return title; }
    public int getCurrentMap() { return currentMap; }
    public List<Item> getItems() { return items; }
    public int[][] getMap() { return map; }

    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
    public void setTitle(String title) { this.title = title; }
    public void setCurrentMap(int currentMap) { this.currentMap = currentMap; }
    public void setItems(List<Item> items) { this.items = items; }
    public void setMap(int[][] map) { this.map = map; }
}
```

and

```
public class Item {
    private String name;
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public int getX() { return x; }
    public int getY() { return y; }

    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
    public void setX(int x) { this.x = x; }
    public void setY(int y) { this.y = y; }
}
```

And convert your JSON as follows:

```
Data data = new Gson().fromJson(json, Data.class);
```

To get the title just do:

```
System.out.println(data.getTitle()); // Map One
```

And to get the map item at x=3 and y=3:

```
System.out.println(data.getMap()[3][3]); // 1
```

And to get the name of the first `Item`:

```
System.out.println(data.getItems().get(0).getName()); // Pickaxe
```

Easy! Converting the other way on is also simple using `Gson#toJson()`.

```
String json = new Gson().toJson(data);
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688099/converting-json-to-java/1688182#1688182) for another complex Gson example.

Comment: Errors tell something about the cause of the problem. Ignoring errors doesn't help us to help you explaining them. You know, once the cause of the problem is *understood*, the solution is nothing than obvious. So, share them with us :)

Comment: It's all here... http://www.googlejsonerror.pastebin.com/N5iDazz8
error + source - what am i doing wrong?

Comment: The JSON key `map` is not properly quoted. You forgot a singlequote in front of `map`.

Comment: Those inner classes are not immediately constructable. Either declare those classes `static`, or put them without `public` modifier at bottom below the current class (i.e. do not nest them!), or just put them standalone in a same package.

Comment: Worked! :-D Thanks. Google Json is go for meeeeeeeeee

Comment: Wait... aww
C:\Users\Dan\Documents\gJson\readGoogle.java:37: 'void' type not allowed here
 System.out.println(System.out.println(data.getMap()[3][3])); // Map One

:(

Comment: `println()` indeed returns nothing (`void`) Reread that line once again, you impatient! ;)

Comment: Ahhhhh whoops. Another mistake. Oooooooooooops. :D Thanks. Yes, I am impatient! :D

Comment: It's called `getItems()` and it returns a `List<Item>`.

Comment: Well, I must have never seen this List<Item> before because it's weird. I tried using data.getItems() but no success... honestly... I fail.

Comment: I added an example in my answer. Again, without errors we can't help you more in detail. Errors tell something about the cause of the problem.

Comment: Oh I didn't see the item one. Thanks.

Comment: `System.out.println(data.getItems().get(0).getName()); // Pickaxe` returns null o_O

Comment: Sorry, can't reproduce it on the posted json (with the quote before `map` fixed). Your problem lies somewhere else.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend this library:
http://www.json.org/java/

You simply have to create a JSONObject from string, and get the name proprety.

```
JSONObject JsonObj = JSONObject( InputStr );
String MapTitle = JsonObj.getString("title");
```

Download the source, and import it into your project: http://www.json.org/java/json.zip

Comment: So I download JSONObject.java and import it. Then I make that...? No examples or nothing sheesh .:S

Comment: Yeah, it's my JSON. Some syntax inside it is incorrect hence the error.

Comment: Download link is broken. Go here instead: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java/zipball/master

Answer (score 1):

The Spring Framework uses Jackson, so that's a fairly good endorsement for Jackson.

[JacksonInFiveMinutes](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes)

See the "Simple Data Binding Example" heading if you just want to use generic Maps.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this just fine with google-gson. I think it'd look something like this:

```
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject object = parser.parse(text).getAsJsonObject();

String title = object.get("title").getAsString();
int currentMap = object.get("currentMap").getAsInt();
...
```

Comment: I just tried that and this error: http://www.googlerrror.pastebin.com/8FFvmTCW

I think my JSON is messed up. It's me, not the libs... :\

Answer (score 1):

As for the error messages.

```
C:\Users\Dan\Documents\readJSON\readJ.java:2: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class json
location: package org
import org.json;
      ^
```

You don't usually name your package the same way the package you want to import, although you can.

You have to either: 1 name it different, 2.- don't put the import

```
C:\Users\Dan\Documents\readJSON\readJ.java:27: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method JSONObject(java.lang.String)
location: class org.json.readJ
JSONObject JsonObj = JSONObject(json);
```

You're missing a "new" there... it should be `new JSONObject(...`

Comment: @Dan, ok, I added a new answer.

Answer (score 1):

> *org.json.JSONException: Expected a ':' after a key at 148 [character 149 line 1]*

Here, your json string is invalid:

```
 + "'map': [ { 1,3,1,1,1,24,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 },"
```

That creates and array with objects inside,  the first object has the attributes `1,3,1` etc without value.

Should be:

```
 + "'map': [ [ 1,3,1,1,1,24,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 ],"
```

For that to be an array with arrays inside.

Or

```
+ "'map': [ { 1:0,3:0,1:0,1:...
```

So you can have attributes 1,3,1 etc with value 0 but... that doesn't make sense

Comment: OK, I got it all sorted out. Now I need to know how map array works cause it's buggin' out for me!

Answer (score 0):

json-lib comes with an example of converting a String to a JSON Object:

http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/snippets.html#Creating_a_JSONObject_from_a_JSON_formatted_string