# JAVA - JSON library that handles circular refrences

Tags: json

Please let me know the JSON Library that can handle circular refrences. If there is any please explain how to use it

Comment: Please post an example of input and output so that we can visualize it better. Knowing about circular references would require pretty a lot of code magic. Don't you maybe mean nested objects? At least, I guess that Gson does what you want. [Here's an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688099/converting-json-to-java/1688182#1688182).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither json-lib nor Gson were able to solve the problem. I then used JACKSON's libraray and it did the trick.

Please refer to the below links.

http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews

http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureBiDirReferences