# Simple Json to Java convertion using GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

I've recently started using GSON library for deserializing JSON that comes from web service but I can't make it work. I decide to test GSON on some simple input - can't make it any simpler and it still doesn't work. I've looked through similar issues like [Converting JSON to Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688099/converting-json-to-java/), all of which suggest similar approach to solution. My guess is that I'm missing something really simple and obvious so a fresh view on the code would probably help.
So here is what I have:

JSON

```
{"A":{"name":"qwrety","value1":1,"value2":2}}
```

Java class

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        String json = /*getting JSON from server*/       
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        A obj = gson.fromJson(json, A.class);
        System.out.println(obj);
    }
}

class A {
    private String name;
    private int value1;
    private int value2;

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public int getValue1() { return value1; }
    public int getValue2() { return value2; }

    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
    public void setValue1(int value1) { this.value1 = value1; }
    public void setValue2(int value2) { this.value2 = value2; }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("name: %s, value1: %d, value2: %d", name, value1, value2);
    }
}
```

What I get in return is

```
name: null, value1: 0, value2: 0
```

Anyone can tell what is wrong with this code?

**UPD**
As @torbinsky and @Kevin-Dolan pointed out, the problem was because Java class structure didn't match the Json format. To fix this I added a new class

```
class Container {
    private A a;

    public A getA() { return a; }

    public void setA(A a) { this.a = a; }

}
```

and changed the deserialisation call to following

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Container obj = gson.fromJson(json, Container.class);

System.out.println(obj.getA());
```

However I anyway get "null" printed out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem is your JSON string.

Try changing:

```
{"A":{"name":"qwrety","value1":1,"value2":2}}
```

to:

```
{"name":"qwrety","value1":1,"value2":2}
```

**EDIT:**
I think the problem might be your JSON string has "A" and that is case-sensitive. Try changing your member variable to an uppercase "A". Sorry I am unable to test at the moment to confirm this.

If the JSON format is fixed then try changing your classes to something similar:

```
class Foo {
private String name;
private int value1;
private int value2;

public String getName() { return name; }
public int getValue1() { return value1; }
public int getValue2() { return value2; }

public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
public void setValue1(int value1) { this.value1 = value1; }
public void setValue2(int value2) { this.value2 = value2; }

public String toString() {
    return String.format("name: %s, value1: %d, value2: %d", name, value1, value2);
}
}
```

and:

```
class Container {
private Foo A;

public Foo getA() { return A; }

public void setA(Foo A) { this.A = A; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you're right, changing json to the one you suggested works, but as I said, I'm getting json from a web service, so I can't really change it's format. Your answer gave me an idea to introduce new class ->
    
    class Container {
        private A a;

        public A getA() { return a; }

        public void setA(A a) { this.a = a; }
    
    }

and deserialize it instead ->

Container obj = gson.fromJson(json, Container.class);

but when I print obj.getA() I still get null

Comment: I think the problem might be your JSON string has "A" and that is case-sensitive. Try changing your member variable to an uppercase "A". Sorry I am unable to test at the moment to confirm this.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, it's looking for a field in your object called "A", but instead it's finding fields "name", "value1" and "value2".

The json you want to be sending to gson is:

```
{"name":"qwrety","value1":1,"value2":2}
```

Answer (score 1):

After changes, your field name is still "a" but JSON uses "A". So you need to either rename field, or add annotation to indicate that JSON uses "A" as name (@SerializedName("A") I think).