# Parse Google Geocode JSON

Tags: java, json, google-maps-api-3

I have this JSON from Google GeoCode and I need to decode this and just get the administrative_area_level_2 and postal_code out of this then I am done. I can parse the results but after that I am not sure how to get the reset of the results. I tried to format this but it was not working. If you follow the link this is the formatted version.

I am trying to do this is JAVA, I know I could do this in PHP but I would rather do this in JAVA. Thank you in advance for your help.

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=false

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "279-281",
               "short_name" : "279-281",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Bedford Ave",
               "short_name" : "Bedford Ave",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Williamsburg",
               "short_name" : "Williamsburg",
               "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Brooklyn",
               "short_name" : "Brooklyn",
               "types" : [ "sublocality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Kings",
               "short_name" : "Kings",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "New York",
               "short_name" : "NY",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "11211",
               "short_name" : "11211",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "279-281 Bedford Ave, Brooklyn, NY 11211, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 40.71450470,
                  "lng" : -73.96128740
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 40.7139010,
                  "lng" : -73.961680
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 40.71422150,
               "lng" : -73.96144540
            },
            "location_type" : "RANGE_INTERPOLATED",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 40.71735047068017,
                  "lng" : -73.95833607931984
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 40.71105522931983,
                  "lng" : -73.96463132068017
               }
            }
         },
         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Williamsburg",
               "short_name" : "Williamsburg",
               "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "New York",
               "short_name" : "New York",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Kings",
               "short_name" : "Kings",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "New York",
               "short_name" : "NY",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Williamsburg, NY, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 40.7182050,
                  "lng" : -73.9202810
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 40.6979330,
                  "lng" : -73.96984510
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 40.70644610,
               "lng" : -73.95361629999999
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 40.7182050,
                  "lng" : -73.9202810
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 40.6979330,
                  "lng" : -73.96984510
               }
            }
         },
         "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "11211",
               "short_name" : "11211",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Brooklyn",
               "short_name" : "Brooklyn",
               "types" : [ "sublocality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "New York",
               "short_name" : "New York",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "New York",
               "short_name" : "NY",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Brooklyn, NY 11211, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 40.7261370,
                  "lng" : -73.92304290
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 40.69763590,
                  "lng" : -73.97616690
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 40.71800360,
               "lng" : -73.96537150000002
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 40.7261370,
                  "lng" : -73.92304290
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 40.69763590,
                  "lng" : -73.97616690
               }
            }
         },
         "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Brooklyn",
               "short_name" : "Brooklyn",
               "types" : [ "sublocality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "New York",
               "short_name" : "New York",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Kings",
               "short_name" : "Kings",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "New York",
               "short_name" : "NY",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Brooklyn, NY, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 40.7394460,
                  "lng" : -73.8333650
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 40.55104190,
                  "lng" : -74.056630
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 40.650,
               "lng" : -73.950
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 40.7394460,
                  "lng" : -73.8333650
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 40.55104190,
                  "lng" : -74.056630
               }
            }
         },
         "types" : [ "sublocality", "political" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Kings",
               "short_name" : "Kings",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "New York",
               "short_name" : "NY",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Kings, New York, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 40.7394460,
                  "lng" : -73.8333650
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 40.55104190,
                  "lng" : -74.056630
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 40.65287620,
               "lng" : -73.95949399999999
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 40.7394460,
                  "lng" : -73.8333650
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 40.55104190,
                  "lng" : -74.056630
               }
            }
         },
         "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "New York",
               "short_name" : "New York",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "New York",
               "short_name" : "New York",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "New York",
               "short_name" : "NY",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "New York, NY, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 40.9175770,
                  "lng" : -73.7002720
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 40.4773990,
                  "lng" : -74.259090
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 40.71435280,
               "lng" : -74.00597309999999
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 40.9175770,
                  "lng" : -73.7002720
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 40.4773990,
                  "lng" : -74.259090
               }
            }
         },
         "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "New York",
               "short_name" : "NY",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "New York, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 45.0158650,
                  "lng" : -71.7774910
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 40.4773990,
                  "lng" : -79.762590
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 43.29942850,
               "lng" : -74.21793260000001
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 45.0158650,
                  "lng" : -71.7774910
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 40.4773990,
                  "lng" : -79.762590
               }
            }
         },
         "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "United States",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 71.53879999999999,
                  "lng" : -66.88507489999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 18.77630,
                  "lng" : 170.59570
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 37.090240,
               "lng" : -95.7128910
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 71.53879999999999,
                  "lng" : -66.88507489999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 18.77630,
                  "lng" : 170.59570
               }
            }
         },
         "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Comment: Have you *tried* using a JSON parsing library?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688099/converting-json-to-java/1688182#1688182 for hints on parsing json in java.

Comment: I can parse the it without errors and the get the above result in a form of string. I am having problems extracting the postal code and admin level 2. This is the part I don't get.

Comment: @Brandon Wilson, it's perhaps a good idea to post the code where you're actually parsing the input.

Comment: What does it mean to "get the administrative_area_level_2"?  What's the value of "administrative_area_level_2"?  Is it "Kings","Kings"?

Comment: @Brandon Wilson: can you please post an answer to the question yourself and then accept that answer? Also, you need to accept answers to previous questions if they fix your problem.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I managed to figure it out. I wrote some code to loop through each object till I got what I needed from the String. I will post the code later today. Thank you for your help. Its just a lot of data, I thought maybe someone would have an easier way.

Comment: There is no code needed guys. He explained is approach and his way he took. That's a hint that can help people to solve this problem, so don't downvote it!