# Configure Jackson to deserialize single quoted (invalid) JSON

Tags: java, jackson

I am a newbie to using jackson library.

I am trying to do this [see below], and it is throwing error.

```
String x="{'candidateId':'k','candEducationId':1,'activitiesSocieties':'Activities for cand1'}";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

try {
    JsonNode df=mapper.readValue(x,JsonNode.class);
    int i=0;
} catch .....
```

Exception:

> ```
> org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character (''' (code 39)): was expecting double-quote to start field name
> at [Source: java.io.StringReader@1afd1810; line: 1, column: 3]
>   at org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1291)
> ```

While the same thing works if I replace the single quote(') with double quote(").

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688099/converting-json-to-java/1688182#1688182                                                   http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Answer (score 81, accepted):

It's not valid JSON, but you can tell Jackson to allow it.  Here's how.

```
String x = "{'candidateId':'k','candEducationId':1,'activitiesSocieties':'Activities for cand1'}";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_SINGLE_QUOTES, true);
JsonNode df = mapper.readValue(x, JsonNode.class);
System.out.println(df.toString());
// output: {"candidateId":"k","candEducationId":1,"activitiesSocieties":"Activities for cand1"}
```

Comment: @Bruce Thanks Bruce for your suggestion. This is exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 16):

Strings in JSON may only be specified using double quotes (`"`), *not* single quotes (`'`), this is the reason for your error; use double quotes.

Here's the pipe diagram that specifies valid JSON strings (note they may only be encapsulated with double quotes!)

[image: Valid JSON Strings Pipe Diagram]
<sub>(source: [json.org](http://www.json.org/string.gif))</sub>

(See [json.org](https://www.json.org/) for a complete specification of JSON.)

Comment: Issue is i can form a absolutely valid json object with single quote in javascript, but am not able to parse that in java. Do I have to replace the single quote with double quote before parsing it with jackson

Comment: @Pipalayan: the problem is that single-quotes are *not* valid in JSON, check out the specification. You cannot parse single quotes using this library because, simply put, you're giving invalid input to your parser.

Comment: "i can form a absolutely valid json object with single quote in javascript" -- JavaScript might allow the single quotes, but that doesn't mean it's valid JSON.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way it works in my case:

```
var jsonString ='{"it":"Stati Uniti d'America"}';
jsonString =jsonString.replace("'", "\\\\u0027");
```