# Configure Play/Jerkson to deserialize single quoted (non-standard) JSON w/o duplicating a lot of code

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0, jackson, jerkson

In a Play 2.0 application, I need to deserialize some JSON from a source which I don't control which uses single-quotes around strings -- where the JSON spec calls for double-quotes.

The solution using Jackson is here:
[Configure Jackson to deserialize single quoted (invalid) JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6591388/178551)

But trying to implement this solution in play2.0 I hit a wall of static objects and private classes... it should be enough to replace object JerksonJson with one implementing the solution linked above at initialization, but because it is a static object it can't be extended, and id I try to copy it into my code I need to drag along classes PlaySerializers, PlayDeserializers, JsValueDeserializer,... I stopped here, as it looked like too much.

Is there a clean solution?

Answer (score 0):

How about trying to fix the invalid json string by replacing every ' in it with a "?

That would work if 's are only used for specifying strings.

Comment: I finally used a Regex to replace all ' not preceded by a \ with a " -- after having replaced all " with \". Then I replaced all \' with '.

Not pretty, but worked. The original question stands to be answered, though.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this may not help too much with Play framework part, but perhaps you could use [Jackson Scala Module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala) instead of Jerkson? Doing that should make it easier to just use `ObjectMapper`, with Scala module registered, instead of having to use Jerkson-specific handlers.