# How to avoid the ‘\’ when appying JSONObject.put operation of two strings to a JSONObject?

Tags: java, json, escaping

The codes is like the following:

```
JSONObject solution = new JSONObject(); 
variableName = "TEST"                   
System.err.println("1:"+value);
solution.put(variableName, value);
System.err.println("2:"+solution);
```

Here is the output result:

```
1:{"min":10,"max":40}
2:{"TEST":"{\"min\":10,\"max\":40}"}
```

How can I get rid of the annoying '\'?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you are getting `\` in your print line is because it is escaping the `"` character which is used in `value`. There's nothing wrong with this, it simply signifies that `\"` is not terminating the string and is instead a value part of that string.

Usage of double quotations is valid JSON, not single quotes - see related Q [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591388/configure-jackson-to-deserialize-single-quoted-invalid-json).

But if you really want to, if you create `value` like this:

```
    JSONObject value = new JSONObject("{'min':10,'max':40}");
```

Then you should get the desired output from your existing code:

```
1:{"min":10,"max":40}
2:{"TEST":{"min":10,"max":40}}
```