# Jackson 2.x single-quote handling

Tags: java, json, jackson

I need to use the Jackson parser to handle json that contains non-standard single quotes instead of double quotes. This question has been asked before:

[Configure Jackson to deserialize single quoted (invalid) JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591388/configure-jackson-to-deserialize-single-quoted-invalid-json?rq=1)

but the "JsonParser" class no longer exists in Jackson 2.0+. It looks like the newer way to configure the ObjectMapper is like this:

```
mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.FEATURE_NAME_HERE);
```

but I can't find an ALLOW_SINGLE_QUOTES feature. Maybe I'm just not seeing it.

How do I deserialize single quotes in Jackson 2.x?

**EDIT**

OOPS, never mind. JsonParser does exist. In my project it was being shadowed by the Json Smart class with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Try `mapper.getFactory().enable(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_SINGLE_QUOTES)`

Comment: Yes. There is also method `ObjectMapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature, state)'