# Can't parse JSON property "null"

Tags: java, json, json-lib

I faced with one trouble when tried to parse JSON "null" property, please help me to understand what's the real problem. I had a following JSON:

```
{
  "properties" : {        
    "null" : {
      "value" : false
    }
  }
}
```

I used http://jsonlint.com to validate that this JSON is valid. I tried to parse it from java:

```
import net.sf.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String st = "{" +
                "      'properties' : {" +
                "        'null' : {" +
                "          'value' : false" +
                "        }" +
                "      }" +
                "}";
        JSONObject.fromObject(st);
    }
}
```

But got the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: JSON keys must be strings.
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject._fromJSONObject(JSONObject.java:927)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.fromObject(JSONObject.java:155)
    at net.sf.json.JSONSerializer.toJSON(JSONSerializer.java:108)
    at net.sf.json.AbstractJSON._processValue(AbstractJSON.java:238)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject._processValue(JSONObject.java:2655)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.processValue(JSONObject.java:2721)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.element(JSONObject.java:1786)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject._fromJSONTokener(JSONObject.java:1036)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject._fromString(JSONObject.java:1201)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.fromObject(JSONObject.java:165)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.fromObject(JSONObject.java:134)
```

I used json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar from http://json-lib.sourceforge.net to parse it. Could anybody please clarify this? Why this library throws exception, but online validator said that it's valid JSON? It is a bug in the library or I made something wrong?

Comment: This isn't the cause of the problem, but `null` is a keyword in JavaScript.  Do you really need to use it as the name of your property?

Comment: @aroth 1) JSON is not JavaScript -- it is a formalized subset of JavaScript literals where object key are required to be surrounding in double-quotes 2) `"null"` is not `null`

Comment: @pst - JSON is not JavaScript, but often you end up working with it in JavaScript (not that this won't work in JavaScript, but it certainly makes for some [confusing looking code](http://jsfiddle.net/SZSm6/)).  And `null` is also a keyword in Java.  That `"null"` is not `null` is immaterial.  It is still semantically vague to call a property `"null"` in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first JSON posted is valid JSON: the JSON in the Java, however, is not valid -- only `"` is valid for the [required] key quote. From [json.org](http://json.org):

> > A string is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, **wrapped in double quotes**, using backslash escapes....

However, that sounds like a bug, *assuming* it was not triggered by the *invalid* JSON fed to it (the library can do whatever it wants with invalid JSON)... one would have to look at the source (or bug reports / user experience) to say conclusively if this is indeed a "bug". I have added some suggestions of things to try below which may either show expected behavior or outline the cause/issue in further detail.

Consider this minimal test-case (with valid JSON):

```
String st = "{ \"null\": \"hello world!\" }";
```

This may also shed more light, depending on if the first item is `"null"` or `null` when extracted:

```
String st = "[ \"null\" ]";
```

Happy coding.

Answer (score 3):

JSON-lib initially parses and populates a Java Map with the input JSON.  Unfortunately, JSON-lib then checks whether every JSON object element name is a JSON `null`.  It's `null` check is performed in the `JSONNull.equals(Object)` method.  This method returns true for a "null" JSON string, which of course is not actually a JSON `null` value.

I recommend filing a bug with the JSON-lib project for this issue.  The implementation of `JSONNull.equals(Object)` is flawed.

Unfortunately, it's not possible to handle this with a custom `PropertyNameProcessor`.

Options available for a more immediate solution include altering the JSON-lib code yourself, or switching libraries.

If you can switch libraries, I highly recommend [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org).  Following is an example of using it to deserialize the example JSON in the original question.

```
/*
{
  "properties" : {        
    "null" : {
      "value" : false
    }
  }
}
 */
String json = "{\"properties\":{\"null\":{\"value\":false}}}";

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue(json, Map.class);
System.out.println(map);
// output: {properties={null={value=false}}}

Map<String, Object> propertiesMap = (Map) map.get("properties");
System.out.println(propertiesMap);
// output: {null={value=false}}

Map<String, Object> nullMap = (Map) propertiesMap.get("null");
System.out.println(nullMap);
// output: {value=false}
```

Answer (score 0):

The gson library link is:

http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

I normally usr gson to generate the josn string,so I found some example someone else posted in stackoverflow to parse json string with gson,see the link:

[Converting JSON to Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688099/converting-json-to-java/1688182#1688182)

Answer (score -1):

suggest you to use Gson,

and construct the json string using java Map and List,
then use Gson to output the Map or List object

Comment: You should add a link to GSON and, ideally, post an example code snippet or link to an example of the approach you describe.

Comment: ok,  I am a new guy here, so the answer may be a little bit simple.I'll post another answer