# net.sf.JSONObject - how to intentionally write the string "null" as a value

Tags: java, json

Let's posit the following theoretical situation: A webapp is describing the odd creatures of the arctic, including an odd long-snouted creature like an anteater that eats arctic frogs, that the Eskimoes call a "nh-oo-l", or more commonly written, a "null".

When writing the data about this creature out to the webapp, we write this line:

```
net.sf.json.JSONObject creatureJson = new JSONObject();
creatureJson.element("name", "null");
```

*However*, this then runs into a problem inside the value parser:

In net.sf.json.AbstractJSON:

```
protected Object _processValue( Object value, JsonConfig jsonConfig ) {
if( JSONNull.getInstance().equals( value ) ) {
     return JSONNull.getInstance();
...
```

In net.sf.json.JSONNull:

```
public boolean equals( Object object ) {
  return object == null || object == this || object == instance
        || (object instanceof JSONObject && ((JSONObject) object).isNullObject())
        || "null".equals( object );
}
```

So what happens as a result is, even though we actually **want** to use "null" as our value (nor do we want the return value to have to process an actual null value), it will come back as a JSONNull, and get printed as `{"name": null}`.

I've been trying to search through net.sf.json's documentation and configuration options for a way around this, but all the behavior seems to be hardcoded in. It's my understanding that this is a very common library. How is it meant to operate in this way?

**NOTE:** To be clear, this is for a situation when *creating* JSON, not *parsing*. There is a similar issue [Can't parse JSON property "null"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687235/cant-parse-json-property-null), but the issue there was that the user was attempting to use single-quotes for parsing; the root issue had absolutely nothing to do with nulls at all.