# POST java object from .jsp to java

Tags: java, html, jsp

I've got a page where the user inputs information into a form and then hits submit. When the submit button is clicked the user POST's data to a java file. I'm using `out.print()` to print Strings but how would I POST an object when the HTML form is submitted?

Comment: What object do you want to pass from jsp page?

Comment: One I've created which contains some Strings and Int's

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253660/passing-object-from-jsp-to-servlet

Comment: @Skizit, Bhesh has given you very useful link. Try it ;)

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question. Do you want to pass a Java(bean) object unmodified around between requests, or do you want to set all submitted parameters of the form in a new Java(bean) object? If the former, then Bhesh has given the correct exact dupe question. If the latter, check this question instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096454/easy-way-of-populating-javabeans-based-on-request-parameters

Answer (score 1):

```
    <form action="/myServlet">
       <input name="uid" type="text" value="testUser"/>
       <input name="pwd" type="password" value="mypwd" />
        <input name="myObj" type="hdden" value="<%=someObject%>"> 
       <input type="submit" />  
    </form>
```

If there is any form like this, when user clicks on submit button.
form will be submitted to the action url  "/myServlet" . here action is servlet or nay action.
we can get the data from the serverside by using  request.getParameter("myObj");

Answer (score 0):

- When submit is clicked the request will go to a servlet.
- In servlet the form data can be obtained.

  Check this example [Simple Servlet example](http://www.servletworld.com/servlet-tutorials/simple-servlet-example.html)
- If an object has to be passed from jsp then [DWR](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html) can be used for this purpose.

  [Here I gave an explanation of how to do in DWR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331308/getting-json-by-dwr-direct-web-remoting/7365631#7365631)

  [Some tutorials for DWR](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/introduction/elsewhere.html)

Comment: I want to send the object from the jsp to the servlet.