# How to return a multidimensional array in jquery ajax call

Tags: jquery, multidimensional-array

I am calling webmethod in order to return string array in jquery. Regular one dimension string array looks like this

```
[WebMethod]
public static string[] GetNewRow() {
    var listOfItems = new List<string>();
    // populate the listOfItems here
    listOfItems.Add("100");
    // more here
    return listOfItems.ToArray();
}
```

Is it possible to return a multidimensional array?

Comment: Can you show what structure would be ideal? Is it really just a [][]?

Comment: Any structured acceptable by jquery. I tried returning multidimensional string (string[,]), but in jquery it is treated as a single dimensional array. I would like to reference it with two params [a][b] if possible

Answer (score 0):

an array ( [] ), in javascript, is numerically indexed. You have to use an object ( {} ) to access it with a named index. the following example is valid in javascript

```
var thing = { a: {'b': 10}};
thing.a['b'] = thing['a'].b + thing['a']['b'] * thing.a.b;
```

you might get info on JSON object, and a function "object_to_json" on your server side language. check [this link for java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688099/converting-json-to-java/1688182#1688182), or [json_encode](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) for php.