# Get the response of a HTTP GET request

Tags: java, http, get

I'd like to use http://www.imdbapi.com/ in Java, but I don't know I can access the http response. I tried the following:

```
public Map<String, String> get(String title)
{
    URL url = new URL("http://www.imdbapi.com/?t=" + title);
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection(); 

    conn.getContent();      

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`URLConnection#getInputStream()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getInputStream%28%29):

```
InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
// ...
```

Or just the shorthand [`URL#openStream()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openStream%28%29) directly:

```
InputStream input = url.openStream();
// ...
```

Once having it, just send it to a [JSON parser](http://json.org) of your choice, such as for example [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/):

```
InputStream input = new URL("http://www.imdbapi.com/?t=" + URLEncoder.encode(title, "UTF-8")).openStream();
Map<String, String> map = new Gson().fromJson(new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8"), new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>(){}.getType());
// ...
```

*(note that I fixed your query string to be properly URL encoded)*

#### See also:

- [Using java.net.URLConnection to fire and handle HTTP requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests)
- [Converting JSON to Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688099/converting-json-to-java/)

Answer (score 1):

When you go the website and type in the sample movie (i did True Grit ) you are actually able to see the response you would be getting. It looks something like this:

```
{"Title":"True Grit","Year":"2010","Rated":"PG-13","Released":"22 Dec 2010","Genre":"Adventure, Drama, Western","Director":"Ethan Coen, Joel Coen","Writer":"Joel Coen, Ethan Coen","Actors":"Jeff Bridges, Matt Damon, Hailee Steinfeld, Josh Brolin","Plot":"A tough U.S. Marshal helps a stubborn young woman track down her father's murderer.","Poster":"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjIxNjAzODQ0N15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwODY2MjMyNA@@._V1._SX320.jpg","Runtime":"1 hr 50 mins","Rating":"8.0","Votes":"51631","ID":"tt1403865","Response":"True"}
```

After knowing this info, you can easily parse your InputStream, which you obtain from your connection.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The below code should get you started. You need to add URL encoding if you are going to send special characters. In-order to parse JSON response you could probably use parser available in java at [link] http://www.JSON.org/

```
package problem;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
public class Test {

public static void main(String args[])
{
 BufferedReader rd;
 OutputStreamWriter wr;

try
{
    URL url = new URL("http://www.imdbapi.com/?i=&t=dexter");
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
    wr.flush();

    // Get the response
    rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
       System.out.println(line);
    }
}
catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }

  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I recomend use [http-request](https://github.com/jsunsoftware/http-request) built on apache http api.

```
private static final HttpRequest<Map<String, String>> HTTP_REQUEST = 
        HttpRequestBuilder.createGet("http://www.imdbapi.com/", 
             new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>{}
        ).build();

public Map<String, String> get(String title) {
   ResponseHandler<Map<String, String>> responseHandler = HTTP_REQUEST.execute("t", title);
   return responseHandler.orElse(Collections.emptyMap()); //returns response parsed as map or empty map when response body is empty
}
```