# Get JSON results in my Java class via Rest call

Tags: java, json, rest, jira-rest-java-api

I have a javascript by which i call a rest api and get a JSON result , I need this result in a java class.

Below is the script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getCurrentTime()
{
var time;
     AJS.$.ajax({
        url: "/rest/vertygosla/1.0/compute/issue/TST-30",
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            time = data.sla;
        } 
     });
     return time[0].remainingTime;
}

alert(""+getCurrentTime())
</script>
```

json Provided by the server
{"issueKey":"TST-30","issueId":11600,"created":"2013-01-31T11:38:38.765+0530","sla":[{"agreementName":"ack times","remainingTime":5860985,"endDate":"2013-01-31T12:00:57.796+0530","startDate":"2013-01-31T11:38:38.781+0530","consumedTime":1339015,"name":"Ack time","id":11000,"delayed":false,"closed":true,"frozen":false}]}

Can someone provide me a similar example in JAVA .

Thanks

Comment: It would help if you provided the JSON which was returned by the server.

Comment: Check [Get the response of a HTTP GET request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8089189/get-the-response-of-a-http-get-request). It is very similar to yours. And answer show how to make a request and parse json.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the json result in Java then you should use the `JRJC` which is a client specifically made for accessing `JIRA REST API` using `Java`. Otherwise you can send a `HTTP` Request in `Java` to get JSON from a url.

EDIT:You can send a `HTTP` request in `Java` or any other language. I prefer `jquery` or `javascript` since you don't have to implement the login procedure. If you are logged into `jira`, you can directly get the `JSON` results without implementing login. `JRJC` client is really slow.

Following is a way of getting `JSON` from `JIRA` in `jquery`:

```
$.getJSON('https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/latest/search?jql=assignee=xyz&expand&jsonp-callback=?', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
});
```

Comment: Thanks , can you provide an example using HTTP request ?

Comment: I already get the value using JQUERY , I need to get it in JAVA .

Answer (score 0):

You can use RestTemplate in java to make a Rest call and then use JSONObject to retrieve the JSON results as java object.

Below is an example:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
try {
    String jsonResult = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);
    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject)new JSONParser().parse(jsonResult);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: You'd better post links to the libs you're using in your code.

Comment: thanks , can you also provide me the imports for the above code .. ? I get unable to resolve exceptions :)

Comment: you need spring web client library for RestTemplate and Java Json library for JSONObject. You must be able to download them from springsource.org and json.org site  **https://repo.springsource.org/libs-release-local/org/springframework/spring/3.2.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-3.2.0.RELEASE-dist.zip**

Comment: Jars required to JSON in java program..
json-lib-2.2.2-jdk15.jar
ezmorph.jar
commons-lang.jar
commons-logging.jar
commons-beanutils.jar
commons-collections.jar

Comment: @zdesam I will try this and let you know how it goes , thanks :)

Comment: @zdesam it says cannot resolve JSONParser , I guess i cant use spring ... cant this be done using default java libs ?