# Parse a JSON to object JAVA without Root

Tags: json, alfresco, xstream

**The response of my service ALFRESCO REST is:**

```
[
{
"role": "SiteManager",
"authority":
{
    "authorityType": "USER",
    "fullName": "admin",
    "userName": "admin",
    "firstName": "Administrator",
    "lastName": "",
    "url": "\/alfresco\/service\/api\/people\/admin"
},
"url": "\/alfresco\/service\/api\/sites\/test3\/memberships\/admin"
}
,
{
"role": "SiteConsumer",
"authority":
{
    "authorityType": "GROUP",
    "shortName": "jamalgg",
    "fullName": "GROUP_jamalgg",
    "displayName": "jamalgg",
    "url": "\/alfresco\/service\/api\/groups\/jamalgg"
},
"url": "\/alfresco\/service\/api\/sites\/test3\/memberships\/GROUP_jamalgg"
}
,
{
"role": "SiteManager",
"authority":
{
    "authorityType": "GROUP",
    "shortName": "ALFRESCO_ADMINISTRATORS",
    "fullName": "GROUP_ALFRESCO_ADMINISTRATORS",
    "displayName": "ALFRESCO_ADMINISTRATORS",
    "url": "\/alfresco\/service\/api\/groups\/ALFRESCO_ADMINISTRATORS"
},
"url": "\/alfresco\/service\/api\/sites\/test3\/memberships\/GROUP_ALFRESCO_ADMINISTRATORS"
}
]
```

**And I want to parse to list of object:**

```
List<Memberships > listMemberships;

public class Memberships {
private String role;
private List<Authority> listAuthority ;
private String url;
}
public class Authority {
private String  authorityType;
private String  shortName;
private String  fullName;
private String  displayName;
private String  url;
}
```

I think that there are two solutions:

1. how to add the tag Memberships to JSON result for encapsulates
   the whole.
2. how to parse JSON result directly to my list

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As answered in [a-better-java-json-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library) I would use the [google-gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library.

Comment: and there is even a example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688099/converting-json-to-java/1688182#1688182

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Ozoli. The answer to my question is:

```
Type targetType = new TypeToken<Collection<Memberships>>() {}.getType();
List<Memberships> list = (List<Memberships>)  new Gson().fromJson(renduJson,targetType);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use http://jsongen.byingtondesign.com/ to generate java code from json response and then use jackson library ( http://jackson.codehaus.org/ ) to bind that response data to your object(s):

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
User user = mapper.readValue(new File("c:\\user.json"), User.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry for not formatting code

```
Type targetType = new TypeToken<Collection<Memberships>>() {}.getType();
List<Memberships> list = (List<Memberships>)new Gson().fromJson(rendu,targetType);
```