# Convert Userdefined Object to a String Object

Tags: java, string, object

I have a user defined class, say

```
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Employee{
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private Calendar dob;
    private Address address;
    private boolean married;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    public Calendar getDob() {
        return dob;
    }
    public void setDob(Calendar dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }
    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
    public boolean isMarried() {
        return married;
    }
    public void setMarried(boolean married) {
        this.married = married;
    }
}
class Address{
    private int doorNo;
    private String streetName;
    private String city;
    public int getDoorNo() {
        return doorNo;
    }
    public void setDoorNo(int doorNo) {
        this.doorNo = doorNo;
    }
    public String getStreetName() {
        return streetName;
    }
    public void setStreetName(String streetName) {
        this.streetName = streetName;
    }
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
}
```

I am creating an object of Employee and populating it with setters. I have to represent the above object to string (encrypted or human-readable) and parse back to get similar object. Actually, I want to save the string equivalent of java object in a file and to read back them to get a java object. I know we have object writing, but they are sensitive to edit. I would prefer if a java object can be converted to String of human readable form. Thanks.

Comment: what do you need is serialization..

Comment: JSON is the way to go for you, pls check my answer below for example code.

Comment: Thanks to all! I have upvoted all the answer! Thanks for your overwhelming response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be looking for the [toString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) method:

> Returns a string representation of the object. In general, the
>   toString method returns a string that "textually represents" this
>   object. The result should be a concise but informative representation
>   that is easy for a person to read. It is recommended that all
>   subclasses override this method.

In your case you would be doing something of the sort (to be added in each of your classes):

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
  return "Name = " + name + ...
}
```

The string can be of any format you wish. To save the object, all that you need to do is to write the text that the toString method returns to a file.

To read them back, however, you will have to implement your own logic. On the other hand, what you can do, is to use something such as [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) (instructions [here](http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html)) which will automatically convert your object to XML.

XML is human readable so that your users can modify whatever they need. Once this is done, you can re-use XStream to read back your object.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot. It is simple and effective. Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

You should override `toString()` to convert instances of your class to string. As for recreating instances based on their string representation you can define a static factory method for this.

```
public class Employee {
  ...
  @Override
  public String toString() {
    ...
  }

  public static Employee fromString(String str) {
    ...
  }
}
```

You use these methods like this:

To obtain string representation of an instance to string:

```
Employee john = ...
String johnString = john.toString();
```

Note that your `toString()` method will also be called implicitly whenever there is a need to obtain string representation of one of the instances.

To recreate an instance from string:

```
Employee john = Employee.fromString(johnString);
```

If you often need to store instances of the class in a file and read them back, you may also consider serialization. See documentation for [Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) interface as well as [ObjectInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html) and [ObjectOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html). You may also want to familiarize yourself with caveats surrounding serialization by reading the last chapter ("Serialization") in [Effective Java, second edition](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/). Most importantly be aware that the serialized form of your class becomes part of your public API.

Comment: The toString() method is okay for representing an object, but for reading them back? Moreover, I have Calendar object, and another user defined object in it. So its difficult to implement our own methods. Is there any available API to do this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: For recreating an instance back from string form I have suggested a static factory method `fromString()`. I have added a demonstration of how to use both methods.

Comment: As for the Calendar instances, you can recreate them based on what is stored in the string produced by `toString()` (you must put enough information to allow this to your string representation). Also, Calendar implements Serializable so you may give consideration to serialization.

Answer (score 3):

To keep your flattened object human readable and hand editable consider encoding your object into a JSON string using one of the popular JSON libraries. Same JSON library will also provide you APIs to decode a JSON string into your object.

One of the popular JSON library is [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). Here's an use example: [Converting JSON to Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688099/converting-json-to-java/1688182#1688182)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Employee em = new Employee;

//Your code

str obj= JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize();

// whenever you want to get object again

Employee emp = (Employee)JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize();
```

Comment: I am not able use that JavaScriptSerializer. Is that from Jdk or external library.