# Javascript- XML syntax error in ajax request $.getJSON in Firefox

Tags: javascript, ajax

Hello I have an ajax request, which gets data as json as callback. The content-type is not displayed in the response header and i get null when i check in the console. My code:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false
    beforeSend: function (jqXHR) {
        ...
    },
    complete: function (jqXHR) {
        ....
    }
});

function loadData(div, url) {
    $('#' + div).jstree({
        core: {
            data: function (node, cb) {
                $.getJSON(url + node.id)
                    .done(function (data, status, xhr) {                        
                        cb.call(this, data);
               .......
```

The response looks like:

[image: Response]

And i get XML processing error: syntax error

I tried adding `'Content-Type': 'appplication/json'` to the `$.ajaxSetup` but there was no change. How can i handle this error. Should it be in the ajaxsetup or in the `$.getJSON` function.

Comment: i don't understand, are you tring to get an XML response by getJson? if so this may helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8909668/how-to-get-json-from-an-xml-response-from-server

Comment: The response is json. But i dont understand how or why i get the xml error.

Comment: if you use  $.ajax() instead of $.getJSON() do you get the same error?

Comment: I have not tried as i was checking to fix it by content-type. But i can just try .

Comment: you can change the content-type in your call, but also the server which supply the response have to got the same content-type for his response.  which is the error you get in console? may the response JSON can be corrupted or not well formatted?

Comment: How can i change in my call using $getjson itself as iam not able to bring to working using $ajax.

Comment: here the official docs of $.ajax() https://api.jquery.com/Jquery.ajax/ an coded example is this `jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url + node.id,
            data: your_call_papameters_object,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
               
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                console.log('error: ' + xhr + ajaxOptions + thrownError);
            }`

Comment: This also doesnt work unfortunately :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by adding the foolowing inside beforeSend :

```
jqXHR.overrideMimeType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
```