# Parsing complex string of JSON in java

Tags: java, json

I want to parse a JSON string which is quite complex. It has somewhat following format

```
           { A:{ list of around 20 objects},B:1}
```

These objects inside A again contains some other objects or the datatypes supported by JSON. I have checked couple of examples and documentations.

I found this example to be helpful 
[Converting JSON to Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688099/converting-json-to-java/1688182#1688182)
but looks like I need to know each and every element of the objects contained. I can write a similar code but before spending so much effort I wanted to check if there is other libraries out there which can do automatic parsing and By just giving the key field I can get those contents.

Comment: Have a look at [JSON.simple](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) should be able to handle the structure with no problem. You do not need to know the exact structure of the JSON. You can just iterate over all of the objects and inter-objects.