# how to parse JSON data from url using java

Tags: java, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parsing JSON from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7467568/parsing-json-from-url)
>   [How to get JSON data from an url in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994676/how-to-get-json-data-from-an-url-in-java)

I have an URL from which I am getting JSON data in an array that I want to parse into string using java. which library is used for parsing data from JSON.

The data which I am getting in an array from URL is like below.

```
[
{
"id":4,
"firstName":"varun",
"lastName":"",
"addressLine1":"new delhi",
"addressLine2":"",
"landmark":"",
"locality":"AIRPORT",
"pincode":"700003"
}]
```

Array has no name.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing JSON from URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7467568/parsing-json-from-url) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994676/how-to-get-json-data-from-an-url-in-java?rq=1 or any of the tenths of questions on Json + Java in SO.

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/9994676/1065525

Comment: question is duplicate but solution dosen't satifies my problem

Comment: I should post a question: Can I throw a dead cat and not hit a question regarding how to parse JSON with Java?

Comment: what's wrong with the answers of the other questions?

Comment: problem is only the data which I am getting in an array from URL has no name it simply in [], like above, so code snippet from which i gone through couldn't use with my case.

Comment: URL I gone through is :http://blog.eviac.com/2011/07/parsing-json-comes-as-response-to-web.html

Answer (score 0):

There are many, one of them is Jackson:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

// json will contain the JSON in a tree
JsonNode json = mapper.readTree(yourURLObject);
```