# Java object from JSON input file

Tags: java, json, file

Hi I have a json input file as follows,

```
{'Latitude':'20',
 'coolness':2.0,
 'altitude':39000,
 'pilot':{'firstName':'Buzz',
          'lastName':'Aldrin'},
 'mission':'apollo 11'}
```

How to create a java object from the json input file.

Thanks

Comment: google has made a library for this: http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Comment: Go to http://www.json.org/ and see the "Java" subsection.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the very simple [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library, with the [Gson#fromJson()](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.3/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#fromJson%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29) method.

Here's an example: [Converting JSON to Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688099/converting-json-to-java)

Comment: If input file may be any JSON file(without particular format),then how to parse it?

Comment: ok i m reading opening and reading the file but how to dynamically generate Data class as shown in example(Converting JSON to Java)

Answer (score 1):

There are more than one APIs that can be used. The simplest one is [`JSONObject`](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html)

Just do the following:

```
JSONObject o = new JSONObject(jsonString);
int alt = o.getInt("altitude");
....
```

there are `getXXX` methods for each type. It basically stores the object as a map. This is a slow API.

You may use Google's [`Gson`](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/), which is an elegant and better library -- slightly more work required than JSONObject. If you are really concerned about speed, use [`Jackson`](http://jackson.codehaus.org/).