# Deserializing json with empty string as unexpected first element

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit

On an Android project, using Retrofit2 with a GsonConverterFactory, I'm having trouble deserializing some irregular yet seemingly valid json. Where I would expect the following from the API response:

```
[
  {
    "0": "someCode",
    "1": "some description",
    "Activitycode": "someCode",
    "description": "some description"
  },
  {
    "0": "someCode2",
    "1": "some description2",
    "Activitycode": "someCode2",
    "description": "some description2"
  },
  ...
```

I'm getting this (notice the empty string as first element):

```
[
  "",
  {
    "0": "someCode",
    "1": "some description",
    "Activitycode": "someCode",
    "description": "some description"
  },
  {
    "0": "someCode2",
    "1": "some description2",
    "Activitycode": "someCode2",
    "description": "some description2"
  },
  ...
```

This json passes validation, but where I'd normally deserialize it to a pojo like this:

```
public class ActivityCode {

    @SerializedName("0")
    @Expose
    private String _0;

    @SerializedName("1")
    @Expose
    private String _1;

    @SerializedName("Activitycode")
    @Expose
    private String Activitycode;

    @SerializedName("description")
    @Expose
    private String description;

    ...
}
```

I'm getting the dreaded `com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at...` exception, for obvious reasons.

My Call is simply:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST
Call<List<ActivityCode>> getActivityCodes(@Url String url,
                                          @Field("cmd") String cmd,
                                          ...
```

Which I'm then executing with `call.enqueue(new Callback<List<ActivityCode>>() ...`

I've done some research but am at a loss as to how to handle this empty string where I'm expecting only a list of ActivityCode objects...

**EDIT**

This json passes validation in every validator I can find, but jsonschema2pojo.org has trouble generating code from it.

Comment: Consider maybe writing your own converter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30897857/custom-converter-for-retrofit

Comment: or custom deserializer that only applies to 1 specific model ?