# retrieve data from a multidimensional JSON map in JAVA

Tags: java, json, hashmap

I am Developing an application using Spring MVC and JSP, what am trying to do is fetch some data from a URL, the URL's data is in JSON encoded multidimensional map.

**For Example:**

```
{"RT":"32",
 "HED":{
     "COMPINF":{
          "CP":"ISIN_CODE|SECTOR|LANGUAGE_CODE"}}}
```

I want to parse this code in the same way it came to me, I was trying to use a multidimensional hashmap but can't realy figure out a way.

What would be the best way to parse this data ?

Comment: your json is invalid check at http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Standard `JSON` lib or `Gson`, you can use either to parse the JSON. Simple & best!

Comment: Do you have fixed structure for JSON data you receive ? or is this standard JSON structure?

Comment: @ajduke well I don't believe i do, the data might come in any form as per its availability

Comment: if it is unstructured, then i don't think so, any JSON library will help you. so,i recommend you to, standardized JSON data which is passed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to use a JSON parser such as Google Gson (https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

edit: Here is a similar question: [Converting JSON to Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688099/converting-json-to-java/1688182#1688182)

Comment: well I checked this question before but will it work with multidimensional maps ?

Comment: as long as what is being passed in is valid JSON, it will go it will be able to go to any depth. Meaning it will look like a multidimensional map once it is parsed