# How do I serialize a JSON object?

Tags: java, json

I have the following JSON string.

```
{"portfolio":"HEXGENFUND","transSrlNo":"1","transCode":"BUY","investReason":"009","inflowOutflow":"I","transDate":"2012-09-01","tradeDate":"2012-09-01","tradeDateUpto":"2012-09-01","tradeTime":"15:46:36","investCategory":"FVTPL","custodian":"DEUTSCHE","holdType":"HOLD","securityType":"INV","security":"9.45SBAI160326","assetClass":"NCD","issuer":"SBAI","marketType":"LIM","tradePriceType":"R","requisitionType":"MS","priceFrom":"343490934332","priceTo":"343490934332","marketPrice":"343490934332","averagePrice":"343490934332","price":"343490934332","quantity":"234","grossAmtTcy":"80376878633688","exchRate":"1","grossAmtPcy":80376878633688,"grossIntTcy":"992.42","grossIntPcy":992.42,"netAmountTcy":80376878634680.42,"netAmountPcy":80376878634680.42,"acquCostTcy":80376878633688,"acquCostPcy":80376878633688,"yieldType":"N","purchaseYield":"0","marketYield":"0","ytm":"-80.07453968","mduration":"0","currPerNav":"0","desiredPerNav":"0","currHolding":"0","noofDays":"0","realGlPcy":0,"realGlTcy":"0","nowLater":"N","isAllocable":"false","acquCostReval":0,"acquCostHisTcy":80376878633688,"acquCostHisPcy":0,"exIntTcy":0,"exIntPcy":0,"accrIntReval":0,"accrIntTcy":0,"accrIntPcy":0,"grossAodTcy":0,"grossAodPcy":0,"grossAodReval":0,"bankAccAmtAcy":80376878634680.42,"bankAccAmtPcy":80376878634680.42,"taxAmountTcy":0,"unrelAmortTcy":0,"unrelAmortPcy":0,"unrelGlTcy":0,"unrelGlPcy":0,"realGlHisTcy":0,"realGlHisPcy":0,"tradeFeesTcy":0,"tradeFeesPcy":0}
```

I have a POJO for the above.

How do I deserialize this to a Object?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library

Comment: 1. http://www.json.org/
2. scroll down until you see "Java"
3. pick and download a library

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting JSON to Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688099/converting-json-to-java)

Comment: Are there any restrictions? Is `String json = "{\"portfolio\":\"HEXGENFUND\",\"transSrlNo\":\"1\",\"transCode\":\"BUY\",..."` what you're looking for?

Comment: Great guys i have edited my question. Please have a look at it.

Answer (score 11):

You can use [**gson library**](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) like this to convert above JSON string to HashMap:

```
Gson gson = new Gson(); // get a new Gson instance

// define a Type for Map<String, String>
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>(){}.getType();

// convert JSON string to a Map<String, String> instance
Map<String, String> map = gson.fromJson(jsonStr, type);
```

#### EDIT (Based your Edited question): For converting JSON to your POJO object

You can convert JSON string to **your custom POJO using gson** like this:

```
// assuming your POJO is of type MyClass
MyClass instance = gson.fromJson(jsonStr, MyClass.class);
```

Comment: AFAIK this is the simplest way to do it. and the GSON library is fairly comprehensive.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to generate the matching java class for the above json string, going with a json generator would be the best solution since the data has many fields.

You may check http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Just paste your json, select JSON as source type and you will have a [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) compatible annotated java class.

Answer (score 3):

Thake a look at this library tutorial: [jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes)

String myJson = new org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(myObject);

Answer (score 2):

There are some JSON libraries that may helps you. 
For example, [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) is a Java library that can be used to convert Java Objects into their JSON representation. It can also be used to convert a JSON string to an equivalent Java object

Answer (score 2):

You can create JSON object by using libraries like gson or JsonOrg. You can take a lokk at the following links for libraries and implementations

```
https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide
http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/
http://json.org/java/
```

Comment: Dont't forget net.sf.json http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/jdk15/net/sf/json/JSONObject.html