# How to parse JSON in java and what are the differences between JSONObect and JSONArray?

Tags: java, json

```
{
    "users":[ {
            "user":"hi","password":"hi"
        }, {
            "user":"test","password":"test"
        }
    ]   
}
```

How to parse this type of JSON Objects?
Please help..

Comment: Check out this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1688182/2024761)!

Comment: SO is not a replacement for search

Comment: @ArunPJohny - In that case, why would you post an answer and encourage it all the more?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a json library like [gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/), [jsonlib](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/) or [jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome).

JSONObject: it is a hash object like Map where key value pairs are used

JSONArray: It is a collection of objects like List

Answer (score 0):

`JSONObject` works like a map with key-value pairs. Eg. Code looks like below :

```
JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
  obj.put("name","Hello");
  obj.put("nickname","Hi");
  StringWriter out = new StringWriter();
  obj.writeJSONString(out);
  String jsonText = out.toString();
  System.out.print(jsonText);
```

`JSONArray` works like a list , Eg, code below:

```
JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
  list.add("Hello");
  list.add(new Integer(100));
  System.out.print(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can differentiate the `JSONArray` & `JSONObject` as below:

**JSONArray**

A **JSONArray** is an ordered sequence of values. Its external text form is a string wrapped in square brackets with commas separating the values.

```
[        {"ircEvent": "PRIVMSG", "method": "newURI", "regex": "^http://.*"},

    {"ircEvent": "PRIVMSG", "method": "deleteURI", "regex": "^delete.*"},

    {"ircEvent": "PRIVMSG", "method": "randomURI", "regex": "^random.*"}

  ]
```

**JSONObject**

A **JSONObject** is an unordered collection of name/value pairs. Its external form is a string wrapped in curly braces with colons between the names and values, and commas between the values and names.

```
  {"bindings": [

    {"ircEvent": "PRIVMSG", "method": "newURI", "regex": "^http://.*"},

    {"ircEvent": "PRIVMSG", "method": "deleteURI", "regex": "^delete.*"},

    {"ircEvent": "PRIVMSG", "method": "randomURI", "regex": "^random.*"}
]
 };
```

You can parse the JSONObject as below:

> ```
>   JSONObject JsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
>   JSONArray JsonArray_ = JsonObject .getJSONArray("users");
>   for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++) {
>      JSONObject record= JsonArray_photo.getJSONObject(i);    
>      parsedObject.user = record.getString("user"); //its the same for all fields 
>      parsedObject.password = record.getString("password");
>      map.add(parsedObject);
>    }
> ```