# Simplest way to read from a JSON file in Java?

Tags: java, json, parsing

I'm relatively new to using JSON and all I really need to do read in a few key value pairs from a JSON file on the file system. 
What I figured I would do is read in the file as a string and then parse it that way but it seems kind of redundant that way.

Here's what my file will be like:

```
 {
 "username" : "myname"
 "domain" : "mydomain"
 }
```

So essentially I need some help making an easy and efficient block of code to read in the key/value pairs. I've been trying to use GSON for the most part and haven't had much luck with examples I've found.

Thanks everyone

Comment: Discussion on question [Converting JSON to Java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1688099/214178) mentions some points about GSon and some alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One other alternative is [JSON.org](http://www.json.org/), in which creating a JSON object from a JSON string requires only one line:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(someJSONString);
```

When you need to access its value, use the functions that the [JSONObject](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html) provides.  For example,

```
String userName = jsonObject.getString("username");
String domainName = jsonObject.getString("mydomain");
```