# Gson - Non static variable cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, gson

Following this [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1688099/2546819) I've run into a problem. This is the JSON I'm trying to parse:

```
{
    "origin": "XX.XX.XXX.XXX"
}
```

Here are the important parts of my three main classes:

DDNS.java

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Net.returnIp();
    System.out.println(Data.origin);
}
```

Net.java

```
static void returnIp() throws UnsupportedEncodingException, MalformedURLException, IOException {
    //Ommited code, all it does is do a GET request to get response
    String responseString = new Scanner(response,"UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A").next();

    Data data = new Gson().fromJson(responseString, Data.class);  
}
```

Data.java

```
public class Data {
    public String origin;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("ip:%s", origin);
    }
}
```

Unless I overlooked something in the answer, I'm not completely sure what I'm doing wrong, although I have a rough idea. Could someone please explain why this is happening? Thanks.

Comment: `origin` isn't `static`.

Comment: @user3580294 Yeah, I could get that far, but I'm extremely new to Java and don't fully understand static objects. I can't just declare it static, so how would I fix it? Thanks you for your input.

Comment: What azurefrog said. If a class member isn't `static`, you need to access it through an instance of your class. So you're going to need to get a `Data` object from somewhere.

Comment: @azurefrog Could you provide an example an an answer? As a really new user to Java, this is already over my head. Looks like I have some more learning to do.

Comment: I've converted my comments into an answer so I'd have enough room to explain things.

Comment: @Novicode - Read the Answers to the linked Question.  It has examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to access a non-static member of `Data` in your main method, without having actually a reference to a `Data` object.

The easiest way I can think of to fix this is to change `Net#returnIp()` to return the `Data` it creates when parsing the json:

```
//Net.java
static Data returnIp() throws UnsupportedEncodingException, MalformedURLException, IOException {
    //Ommited code, all it does is do a GET request to get response
    String responseString = new Scanner(response,"UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A").next();

    return new Gson().fromJson(responseString, Data.class);  
}
```

Then you can use the `Data` object you have created:

```
//DDNS.java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Data data = Net.returnIp();
    System.out.println(data);  // this will automatically call data's toString() and format its origin
}
```

The concepts of **Objects** and **Classes** are very fundamental to the Java language.  You will need to understand them to get very far.

I would recommend reading oracle's [Object-Oriented Programming Concepts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html), starting with the "What is an Object?" and "What is a Class?" links.