# not results parsing json

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

I´m parsing JSON for my Android app but I am not able to get data, I am locked, I can´t see my issue, somebody can help me? This is my code, In log cat I get the message, "No value for ticket_price"

```
 private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    super.onPreExecute();
                    // Create a progressdialog
                    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                    // Set progressdialog title
                    //mProgressDialog.setTitle("Android JSON Parse Tutorial");
                    // Set progressdialog message
                    mProgressDialog.setMessage("Actualizando...");
                    mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                    // Show progressdialog
                    mProgressDialog.show();
                }

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    // Create an array
                    arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                    // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
                    jsonobject = JSONfunctions
                            .getJSONfromURL("url");

                    try {
                        // Locate the array name in JSON
                        if(jsonobject == null) 
                            return null; 

                        JSONObject subObjuno = jsonobject.getJSONObject("response");

                        jsonMainNode = subObjuno.getJSONArray("gigs");



                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            jsonobjectdos = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
                            // Retrive JSON Objects

                            map.put("name", jsonobjectdos.getString("name"));



                            //BLOQUE ARTISTS
                            jsonarraydos = jsonobjectdos.getJSONArray("artists");

                            for (int j = 0; j < jsonarraydos.length(); j++){
                                jsonobjectres = jsonarraydos.getJSONObject(i);

                                map.put("url", jsonobjectres.getString("url"));
                                map.put("art_logo", jsonobjectres.getString("art_logo"));
                            }

                            //BLOQUE VENUE
                            JSONObject subObj = jsonobjectdos.getJSONObject("venue");
                            map.put("name", subObj.getString("name"));
                            map.put("venue_logo", subObj.getString("venue_logo"));


                            JSONObject subObjdos = subObj.getJSONObject("location");
                            map.put("city", subObjdos.getString("city"));
                            map.put("country", subObjdos.getString("country"));
                            map.put("street", subObjdos.getString("street"));
                            map.put("postalcode", subObjdos.getString("postalcode"));
                            map.put("latitude", subObjdos.getString("latitude"));
                            map.put("longitude", subObjdos.getString("longitude"));

                            map.put("url", subObj.getString("url"));


                            map.put("tickets_url", jsonobjectdos.getString("tickets_url"));

                            //PRECIO
                            JSONObject subObjtres = jsonobjectdos.getJSONObject("ticket_price");
                            map.put("min", subObjtres.getString("min"));
                            map.put("max", subObjtres.getString("max"));

                            map.put("startDate", jsonobjectdos.getString("startDate"));
                            map.put("description", jsonobjectdos.getString("description"));

                            //IMAGES
                            JSONObject subObjtcuatro = jsonobjectdos.getJSONObject("images");
                            map.put("large", subObjtcuatro.getString("large"));


                            arraylist.add(map);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {

                    if(arraylist == null || arraylist.size() == 0){
                         new DownloadJSON().execute();
                         mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                         return;
                    }
                    // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
                    listview = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.lista_horarios_liga);
                    // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
                    adapter = new LazyAdapterConciertosCiudad(getActivity(), arraylist, "fonts/Roboto-Thin.ttf", "fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf");
                    // Set the adapter to the ListView
                    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
                    // Close the progressdialog
                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
```

The json result from the url is like this:

```
{"status": "success", "response": 
{"gigs": [
{
"id": 2025081,
"name": "Fink",
"artists": [
{
"id": "45329",
"url": "http://www.nvivo.es/artistas/Fink",
"name": "Fink",
"art_logo": "http://d36jiqg3u1m7g0.cloudfront.net/artistas/131x131/v2_131_thumb_45329_fink.jpg"
}],
"venue": {
"id": 11,
"name": "Kafe Antzokia",
"venue_logo": "http://d36jiqg3u1m7g0.cloudfront.net/salas/143x91/v2_143x91_thumb_11_kabsarrera.jpg",
"location": {
"city": "Bilbao",

"country": "Spain",
"street": "Calle San Vicente, 2",
"postalcode": "48001",
"latitude": "43.2637",
"longitude": "-2.92805"},
"url": "http://www.nvivo.es/kafe-antzokia-salas-11"
},

"tickets_url": "http://www.nvivo.es/conciertos/Fink-Bilbao",
"ticket_price": {
"min": 16.00,
"max": 16.00},
"startDate": "2015-03-13 22:00:00",
"modDate": "2015-03-13 20:02:50",
"description": "",
"images": {
"small": "http://d36jiqg3u1m7g0.cloudfront.net/artistas/80x80/v2_80_thumb_45329_fink.jpg",
"medium": "http://d36jiqg3u1m7g0.cloudfront.net/artistas/131x131/v2_131_thumb_45329_fink.jpg",
"large": "http://d36jiqg3u1m7g0.cloudfront.net/artistas/338x236/v2_338x236_thumb_45329_fink.jpg"
},
"attendance": "0",
"tag": "fivegig:gig=2025081",
"url": "http://www.nvivo.es/conciertos/Fink-Bilbao"

},

{
"id": 2214468,
"name": "Jesús Sangui",
"artists": [
{
"id": "5112572",
"url": "http://www.nvivo.es/artistas/Jes%C3%BAs+Sangui",
"name": "Jesús Sangui",
"art_logo": ""
}],
"venue": {
"id": 33738,
"name": "Café La Granja",
"venue_logo": "",
"location": {
"city": "Bilbao",

"country": "Spain",
"street": "Plaza Circular, 3",
"postalcode": "",
"latitude": "43.2614",
"longitude": "-2.92733"},
"url": "http://www.nvivo.es/cafe-la-granja-salas-33738"
},
"startDate": "2015-03-13 22:00:00",
"modDate": "2015-02-26 18:49:00",
"description": "",
"images": {
"small": "",
"medium": "",
"large": ""
},
"attendance": "0",
"tag": "fivegig:gig=2214468",
"url": "http://www.nvivo.es/conciertos/Jes%C3%BAs+Sangui-Bilbao"

},

{
"id": 2218606,
"name": "Sumrrá",
"artists": [
{
"id": "741214",
"url": "http://www.nvivo.es/artistas/Sumrr%C3%A1",
"name": "Sumrrá",
"art_logo": "http://d36jiqg3u1m7g0.cloudfront.net/artistas/131x131/v2_131_thumb_741214_sumrr__.jpg"
}],
"venue": {
"id": 128886,
"name": "La Ribera",
"venue_logo": "",
"location": {
"city": "Bilbao",

"country": "Spain",
"street": "Erribera Kalea, 20, 48005 Bilbao, Bizkaia, España",
"postalcode": "",
"latitude": "43.2563",
"longitude": "-2.92513"},
"url": "http://www.nvivo.es/la-ribera-salas-128886"
},
"startDate": "2015-03-14 00:00:00",
"modDate": "2015-02-27 14:09:40",
"description": "",
"images": {
"small": "http://d36jiqg3u1m7g0.cloudfront.net/artistas/80x80/v2_80_thumb_741214_sumrr__.jpg",
"medium": "http://d36jiqg3u1m7g0.cloudfront.net/artistas/131x131/v2_131_thumb_741214_sumrr__.jpg",
"large": "http://d36jiqg3u1m7g0.cloudfront.net/artistas/338x236/v2_338x236_thumb_741214_sumrr__.jpg"
},
"attendance": "1",
"tag": "fivegig:gig=2218606",
"url": "http://www.nvivo.es/conciertos/Sumrr%C3%A1-Bilbao"

},

{
"id": 1997788,
"name": "Lagwagon, The Flatliners, Western Addiction",
"artists": [
{
"id": "220494",
"url": "http://www.nvivo.es/artistas/Lagwagon",
"name": "Lagwagon",
"art_logo": "http://d36jiqg3u1m7g0.cloudfront.net/artistas/131x131/v2_131_thumb_220494_lagwagon_gira_conciertos_abr.jpg"
},
{
"id": "196192",
"url": "http://www.nvivo.es/artistas/The+Flatliners",
"name": "The Flatliners",
"art_logo": "http://d36jiqg3u1m7g0.cloudfront.net/artistas/131x131/v2_131_thumb_196192_flatliners1_web.jpg"
},
{
"id": "158123",
"url": "http://www.nvivo.es/artistas/Western+Addiction",
"name": "Western Addiction",
"art_logo": "http://d36jiqg3u1m7g0.cloudfront.net/artistas/131x131/v2_131_thumb_158123_western_addiction.jpg"
}],
"venue": {
"id": 200,
"name": "Santana 27",
"venue_logo": "http://d36jiqg3u1m7g0.cloudfront.net/salas/143x91/v2_143x91_thumb_200_ficha_foto_santana27.jpg",
"location": {
"city": "Bilbao",

"country": "Spain",
"street": "Calle Tellería, 27",
"postalcode": "",
"latitude": "43.2824",
"longitude": "-2.98176"},
"url": "http://www.nvivo.es/santana-27-salas-200"
},

"tickets_url": "http://www.nvivo.es/conciertos/Lagwagon-Bilbao",
"ticket_price": {
"min": 22.00,
"max": 52.74},
"startDate": "2015-03-14 19:00:00",
"modDate": "2015-03-13 21:02:24",
"description": "",
"images": {
"small": "http://d36jiqg3u1m7g0.cloudfront.net/carteles/62x62/v2_62_thumb__lagwagon_flatliners_vans_tou.jpg",
"medium": "http://d36jiqg3u1m7g0.cloudfront.net/carteles/131x131/v2_131_thumb__lagwagon_flatliners_vans_tou.jpg",
"large": "http://d36jiqg3u1m7g0.cloudfront.net/carteles/239xY/v2_239xY_thumb__lagwagon_flatliners_vans_tou.jpg"
},
"attendance": "1",
"tag": "fivegig:gig=1997788",
"url": "http://www.nvivo.es/conciertos/Lagwagon-Bilbao"

},

{
"id": 2025097,
"name": "Maika Makovski",
"artists": [
{
"id": "256064",
"url": "http://www.nvivo.es/artistas/Maika+Makovski",
"name": "Maika Makovski",
"art_logo": "http://d36jiqg3u1m7g0.cloudfront.net/artistas/131x131/v2_131_thumb_256064_maika_makovski.jpg"
}],
"venue": {
"id": 11,
"name": "Kafe Antzokia",
"venue_logo": "http://d36jiqg3u1m7g0.cloudfront.net/salas/143x91/v2_143x91_thumb_11_kabsarrera.jpg",
"location": {
"city": "Bilbao",

"country": "Spain",
"street": "Calle San Vicente, 2",
"postalcode": "48001",
"latitude": "43.2637",
"longitude": "-2.92805"},
"url": "http://www.nvivo.es/kafe-antzokia-salas-11"
},

"tickets_url": "http://www.nvivo.es/conciertos/Maika+Makovski-Bilbao",
"ticket_price": {
"min": 15.00,
"max": 15.00},
"startDate": "2015-03-14 22:00:00",
"modDate": "2015-03-13 20:03:02",
"description": "",
"images": {
"small": "http://d36jiqg3u1m7g0.cloudfront.net/artistas/80x80/v2_80_thumb_256064_maika_makovski.jpg",
"medium": "http://d36jiqg3u1m7g0.cloudfront.net/artistas/131x131/v2_131_thumb_256064_maika_makovski.jpg",
"large": "http://d36jiqg3u1m7g0.cloudfront.net/artistas/338x236/v2_338x236_thumb_256064_maika_makovski.jpg"
},
"attendance": "0",
"tag": "fivegig:gig=2025097",
"url": "http://www.nvivo.es/conciertos/Maika+Makovski-Bilbao"

},

{
"id": 2275759,
"name": "Ray Fernandez",
"artists": [
{
"id": "5112819",
"url": "http://www.nvivo.es/artistas/Ray+Fernandez",
"name": "Ray Fernandez",
"art_logo": ""
}],
"venue": {
"id": 11,
"name": "Kafe Antzokia",
"venue_logo": "http://d36jiqg3u1m7g0.cloudfront.net/salas/143x91/v2_143x91_thumb_11_kabsarrera.jpg",
"location": {
"city": "Bilbao",

"country": "Spain",
"street": "Calle San Vicente, 2",
"postalcode": "48001",
"latitude": "43.2637",
"longitude": "-2.92805"},
"url": "http://www.nvivo.es/kafe-antzokia-salas-11"
},

"tickets_url": "http://www.nvivo.es/conciertos/Ray+Fernandez-Bilbao",
"ticket_price": {
"min": 8.00,
"max": 8.00},
"startDate": "2015-03-15 19:00:00",
"modDate": "2015-03-13 20:03:14",
"description": "",
"images": {
"small": "",
"medium": "",
"large": ""
},
"attendance": "0",
"tag": "fivegig:gig=2275759",
"url": "http://www.nvivo.es/conciertos/Ray+Fernandez-Bilbao"

},

{
"id": 2020784,
"name": "Joan Baez",
"artists": [
{
"id": "155807",
"url": "http://www.nvivo.es/artistas/Joan+Baez",
"name": "Joan Baez",
"art_logo": "http://d36jiqg3u1m7g0.cloudfront.net/artistas/131x131/v2_131_thumb_155807_imagen_2.jpg"
}],
"venue": {
"id": 886,
"name": "Palacio Euskalduna",
"venue_logo": "http://d36jiqg3u1m7g0.cloudfront.net/salas/143x91/v2_143x91_thumb_886_palacio_euskalduna.jpg",
"location": {
"city": "Bilbao",

"country": "Spain",
"street": "Avenida Abandoibarra, 4",
"postalcode": "",
"latitude": "43.2688",
"longitude": "-2.93732"},
"url": "http://www.nvivo.es/palacio-euskalduna-salas-886"
},

"tickets_url": "http://www.nvivo.es/conciertos/Joan+Baez-Bilbao",
"ticket_price": {
"min": 120.00,
"max": 120.00},
"startDate": "2015-03-17 00:00:00",
"modDate": "2015-03-13 21:02:46",
"description": "",
"images": {
"small": "http://d36jiqg3u1m7g0.cloudfront.net/artistas/80x80/v2_80_thumb_155807_imagen_2.jpg",
"medium": "http://d36jiqg3u1m7g0.cloudfront.net/artistas/131x131/v2_131_thumb_155807_imagen_2.jpg",
"large": "http://d36jiqg3u1m7g0.cloudfront.net/artistas/338x236/v2_338x236_thumb_155807_imagen_2.jpg"
},
"attendance": "0",
"tag": "fivegig:gig=2020784",
"url": "http://www.nvivo.es/conciertos/Joan+Baez-Bilbao"

},

{
"id": 2103269,
"name": "El Pimiento Indomable",
"artists": [
{
"id": "5111770",
"url": "http://www.nvivo.es/artistas/El+Pimiento+Indomable",
"name": "El Pimiento Indomable",
"art_logo": ""
}],
"venue": {
"id": 11,
"name": "Kafe Antzokia",
"venue_logo": "http://d36jiqg3u1m7g0.cloudfront.net/salas/143x91/v2_143x91_thumb_11_kabsarrera.jpg",
"location": {
"city": "Bilbao",

"country": "Spain",
"street": "Calle San Vicente, 2",
"postalcode": "48001",
"latitude": "43.2637",
"longitude": "-2.92805"},
"url": "http://www.nvivo.es/kafe-antzokia-salas-11"
},

"tickets_url": "http://www.nvivo.es/conciertos/El+Pimiento+Indomable-Bilbao",
"ticket_price": {
"min": 15.00,
"max": 15.00},
"startDate": "2015-03-18 22:00:00",
"modDate": "2015-03-13 14:03:18",
"description": "",
"images": {
"small": "",
"medium": "",
"large": ""
},
"attendance": "0",
"tag": "fivegig:gig=2103269",
"url": "http://www.nvivo.es/conciertos/El+Pimiento+Indomable-Bilbao"

},

{
"id": 2209200,
"name": "The Limboos",
"artists": [
{
"id": "5090540",
"url": "http://www.nvivo.es/artistas/The+Limboos",
"name": "The Limboos",
"art_logo": ""
}],
"venue": {
"id": 11,
"name": "Kafe Antzokia",
"venue_logo": "http://d36jiqg3u1m7g0.cloudfront.net/salas/143x91/v2_143x91_thumb_11_kabsarrera.jpg",
"location": {
"city": "Bilbao",

"country": "Spain",
"street": "Calle San Vicente, 2",
"postalcode": "48001",
"latitude": "43.2637",
"longitude": "-2.92805"},
"url": "http://www.nvivo.es/kafe-antzokia-salas-11"
},

"tickets_url": "http://www.nvivo.es/conciertos/The+Limboos-Bilbao",
"ticket_price": {
"min": 10.00,
"max": 10.00},
"startDate": "2015-03-18 23:00:00",
"modDate": "2015-03-13 20:02:51",
"description": "",
"images": {
"small": "",
"medium": "",
"large": ""
},
"attendance": "0",
"tag": "fivegig:gig=2209200",
"url": "http://www.nvivo.es/conciertos/The+Limboos-Bilbao"

},

{
"id": 2095852,
"name": "Carvin Jones Band, Jimmy Barnatán",
"artists": [
{
"id": "257422",
"url": "http://www.nvivo.es/artistas/Carvin+Jones+Band",
"name": "Carvin Jones Band",
"art_logo": "http://d36jiqg3u1m7g0.cloudfront.net/artistas/131x131/v2_131_thumb_257422_carvinjonesband1_web.jpg"
},
{
"id": "5035961",
"url": "http://www.nvivo.es/artistas/Jimmy+Barnat%C3%A1n",
"name": "Jimmy Barnatán",
"art_logo": ""
}],
"venue": {
"id": 11,
"name": "Kafe Antzokia",
"venue_logo": "http://d36jiqg3u1m7g0.cloudfront.net/salas/143x91/v2_143x91_thumb_11_kabsarrera.jpg",
"location": {
"city": "Bilbao",

"country": "Spain",
"street": "Calle San Vicente, 2",
"postalcode": "48001",
"latitude": "43.2637",
"longitude": "-2.92805"},
"url": "http://www.nvivo.es/kafe-antzokia-salas-11"
},

"tickets_url": "http://www.nvivo.es/conciertos/Carvin+Jones+Band-Bilbao",
"ticket_price": {
"min": 12.00,
"max": 12.00},
"startDate": "2015-03-19 21:00:00",
"modDate": "2015-03-13 20:02:34",
"description": "",
"images": {
"small": "http://d36jiqg3u1m7g0.cloudfront.net/artistas/80x80/v2_80_thumb_257422_carvinjonesband1_web.jpg",
"medium": "http://d36jiqg3u1m7g0.cloudfront.net/artistas/131x131/v2_131_thumb_257422_carvinjonesband1_web.jpg",
"large": "http://d36jiqg3u1m7g0.cloudfront.net/artistas/338x236/v2_338x236_thumb_257422_carvinjonesband1_web.jpg"
},
"attendance": "1",
"tag": "fivegig:gig=2095852",
"url": "http://www.nvivo.es/conciertos/Carvin+Jones+Band-Bilbao"

}]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might simply be that your data has no "ticket_price" for some gigs. 
In that case, you may want to consider [optString](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#optString(java.lang.String))

You can quickly explore your json in the Javascript console feature in most browsers.

Just pop your json into a `var`

`var str = {"your_json" : "here"}`

Then you can do something like this..

```
for (var gig in str.response.gigs){        
   console.log(str.response.gigs[gig].ticket_price);
}
```

And see some output like this

```
Object {min: 16, max: 16}
undefined
Object {min: 22, max: 52.74}
Object {min: 15, max: 15}
Object {min: 8, max: 8}
Object {min: 120, max: 120}
Object {min: 15, max: 15}
Object {min: 10, max: 10}
Object {min: 12, max: 12}
```

In addition, you could consider looking for other methods of parsing Json.  For example 
[Converting JSON to Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688099/converting-json-to-java)