# JSON request to Java data structure

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

I have following JSON request:

```
{
    "one":{
        "key":"value",
        "key":"value",
        "key":"value"
    },
    "two":[
        "value"
    ],
    "three":[
        "value"
    ],
    "four":[
        "value"
    ]
}
```

How can I represent it as a Java object/data structure? I can normally take JSON starting from `"two"` and handle it as follows:

```
@RequestBody Map<String, List<String>> inputParams
```

any suggestions?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688099/converting-json-to-java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688099/converting-json-to-java)

Comment: it is the format may change for 2 requests ?

Comment: @ma3stro nope, this isn't method I want to use. Something better from Spring, JAXB etc.

Comment: @davidhxxx no, it must be single request.

Comment: Which JSON parser do you use? Jackson?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
 Map<String, Object> inputParams;

 InnerObj innerObj = (InnerObj)inputParams.get("one");
 List<String> secondList = (List)inputParams.get("two");
 List<String> thirdLisr = (List)inputParams.get("three");
 '''
```

where

```
class InnerObj {
    String key1;
    String key2;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems legit and appropriate for me as I don't want to use a lot of external libs.

Comment: but there's one issue: i'm getting java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to SomeObject.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google GSON https://github.com/google/gson and parse your json to POJO and than use it. For example:

`{
        "key1":"value1",
        "key2":"value2",
        "key3":"value3"
}`

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
MyObj myObj = gson.fromJson(jsonObj, MyObj.class);
```

Where MyObj.java:

```
public class MyObj {
    String key1;
    String key2;
    String key3;
}
```

And in your controller you can use `@RequestParam(value = "jsonObjFromClient") String jsonObj` annotation.