# Issues with accessing REST service from command line program

Tags: java, command-line, jax-rs, webclient

I am trying to create a command line Java program which has to access some REST services. I referred one of the springs webapp which does the same using autowiring. I could see the below in the spring config file of the webapp.

```
<bean id="jacksonJsonProvider" class="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider" />

<util:list id="webClientProviders">     
    <ref bean="jacksonJsonProvider"/>
</util:list> 

<bean id="jsonWebClient" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient" factory-method="create">
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="http://localhost:8080/"/> 
    <constructor-arg ref="webClientProviders" /> 
</bean>
```

This tells me that spring will create an instance of WbClient using the arguments 'http://localhost:8080/' and a List having an instance of JacksonJsonProvider. Is my understand correct?

I also see the below usage in the webapp code.

```
@Controller
public class ABController {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("jsonWebClient")
    private WebClient webclient;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/abc.action", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public String getABCD(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        ...
        ...
        WebClient wc = WebClient.create(webclient.getBaseURI());
        wc.path("abcdservices/rest/restservices/cart/gettotal");
        Response res = wc.get();
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

But when I do the same in my Java program, as shown below (and some variants):

```
List<Object> providers = new ArrayList<Object>();
JacksonJsonProvider j = new JacksonJsonProvider();
providers.add(j);
WebClient webclient = WebClient.create("http://localhost:8080/", 
            providers);
WebClient wc = webclient.create(webclient.getBaseURI());
wc.path("crmitsm/rest/cirestservices/crmitsm/warrantystatus");
Response res = wc.get();
```

I get the below exception / error.

```
java -jar target/CmdLine-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.AbstractClient.setupOutInterceptorChain(AbstractClient.java:887)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.AbstractClient.createMessage(AbstractClient.java:958)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.finalizeMessage(WebClient.java:1118)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.doChainedInvocation(WebClient.java:1091)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.doInvoke(WebClient.java:894)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.doInvoke(WebClient.java:865)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.invoke(WebClient.java:331)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.get(WebClient.java:357)
    at org.CmdLine.App.main(App.java:37)
```

Could anybody please help me here. I am not able to understand what I am missing here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I had posted could be some dependency issue. I tried multiple solutions posted for similar problems - all being adding more dependencies, tried with shred plugin instead of assembly etc., but none worked.

Finally I decided to go with HttpClient and it worked fine. Also I decided to use Gson from Google to do the JSON to Java transformation. My program is now working fine. More info about Gson can be found at [Converting JSON to Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688099/converting-json-to-java/1688182#1688182).

Answer (score 0):

The util:List you see in spring config is not exactly the same as a java.util.List you used in your code. At runtime the util:list translates to a list behind a spring proxy. You can print out its class and verify this. So the WebClient creation fails with NullPointerException because spring probably expects a proxy where you passed a j.u.List.

Why do you programmatically create the jsonprovider and webclient? May be you have a reason but making it configurable is more 'reusable'.

Comment: I am trying to do this from a Client Program which is a simple java application and not using spring.

Comment: You can find the correct way to write a CXF webclient [here](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-client-api.html#JAX-RSClientAPI-CXFWebClientAPI)