# How to create a Model for this JSON?

Tags: android, retrofit2, json

In the following `json` there are two product objects, the products keep changing some times there are more than  100 products (I tried `json` to `pojo` converter but it has two for two products inside the main class) ... the products are dynamic ... I am using retrofit

```
{
  "1": {
    "entity_id": "11",
    "type_id": "virtual",
    "sku": "JIG0001VEN",
    "name": "Test Chanakya",
    "meta_title": "Test Chanakya",
    "meta_description": "Test Chanakya",
    "brand_name": "Chanakya",
    "language": "English",
    "no_test_attempts": "4",
    "product_type": "25",
    "difficulty_level": "20",
    "jigno_certified": "18",
    "ca_related": "23",
    "description": "Test Chanakya",
    "short_description": "Test Chanakya",
    "meta_keyword": "Test Chanakya",
    "regular_price_with_tax": 4500,
    "regular_price_without_tax": 4500,
    "final_price_with_tax": 4500,
    "final_price_without_tax": 4500,
    "is_saleable": true
  },
  "2": {
    "entity_id": "12",
    "type_id": "virtual",
    "sku": "JIG5555GENESIS",
    "name": "Genesis Mentors GMAT Mock - 01",
    "meta_title": "Genesis GMAT",
    "brand_name": "Genesis Mentors",
    "language": "English",
    "meta_description": "Genesis GMAT",
    "no_test_attempts": "3",
    "product_type": "25",
    "difficulty_level": "21",
    "jigno_certified": "18",
    "ca_related": "23",
    "description": "Exhaustive national level ",
    "meta_keyword": "GMAT, Genesis, Management",
    "short_description": "Genesis Mentors GMAT Mock",
    "regular_price_with_tax": 199,
    "regular_price_without_tax": 199,
    "final_price_with_tax": 199,
    "final_price_without_tax": 199,
    "is_saleable": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Check this http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways:

**First method is using Gson**

Please have a look at [this library(Gson)](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide).

*You can find on this platform thousands of questions about [how to use Gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688099/converting-json-to-java)*

---

**Second way is using Android default libraries**

You simply have a list of products objects, so you need to use a [JSONArray](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html) after you can iterate each [JSONObject](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) inside this array using this library and converting it into a model.

Since it's easy i'm not going to post the complete object. simply create a class with all values in the object and read about those options.

Comment: yes but the above JSON products 1 and 2 does not have a key and the product names will not be always 1 and 2 its dynamic

Comment: @GowsikCristiano yes, but this is still an Array and those libraries can decode it , you don't need the name

Comment: I used JSON TO POJO converter and got the output but since each product is an object ... I created two classes named _1 and _2 ... this is fine for two  products but i have more than 500 products ... so can u suggest any model

Comment: @GowsikCristiano all the objects are identical, so use the same item for each product you have in the json

Answer (score 1):

You can go through this link to get it in Details ::
http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

**OR**

Here is the solution..

```
package com.example.models;

public class ExampleResponse {

DemoClassForOne _1;
DemoClassForOne _2;

public DemoClassForOne get_1() {
    return _1;
}

public void set_1(DemoClassForOne _1) {
    this._1 = _1;
}

public DemoClassForOne get_2() {
    return _2;
}

public void set_2(DemoClassForOne _2) {
    this._2 = _2;
}

public class DemoClassForOne{

    private String entityId;
    private String typeId;
    private String sku;
    private String name;
    private String metaTitle;
    private String metaDescription;
    private String brandName;
    private String language;
    private String noTestAttempts;
    private String productType;
    private String difficultyLevel;
    private String jignoCertified;
    private String caRelated;
    private String description;
    private String shortDescription;
    private String metaKeyword;
    private Integer regularPriceWithTax;
    private Integer regularPriceWithoutTax;
    private Integer finalPriceWithTax;
    private Integer finalPriceWithoutTax;
    private Boolean isSaleable;


    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The entityId
     */
    public String getEntityId() {
        return entityId;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param entityId
     * The entity_id
     */
    public void setEntityId(String entityId) {
        this.entityId = entityId;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The typeId
     */
    public String getTypeId() {
        return typeId;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param typeId
     * The type_id
     */
    public void setTypeId(String typeId) {
        this.typeId = typeId;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The sku
     */
    public String getSku() {
        return sku;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param sku
     * The sku
     */
    public void setSku(String sku) {
        this.sku = sku;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param name
     * The name
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The metaTitle
     */
    public String getMetaTitle() {
        return metaTitle;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param metaTitle
     * The meta_title
     */
    public void setMetaTitle(String metaTitle) {
        this.metaTitle = metaTitle;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The metaDescription
     */
    public String getMetaDescription() {
        return metaDescription;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param metaDescription
     * The meta_description
     */
    public void setMetaDescription(String metaDescription) {
        this.metaDescription = metaDescription;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The brandName
     */
    public String getBrandName() {
        return brandName;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param brandName
     * The brand_name
     */
    public void setBrandName(String brandName) {
        this.brandName = brandName;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The language
     */
    public String getLanguage() {
        return language;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param language
     * The language
     */
    public void setLanguage(String language) {
        this.language = language;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The noTestAttempts
     */
    public String getNoTestAttempts() {
        return noTestAttempts;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param noTestAttempts
     * The no_test_attempts
     */
    public void setNoTestAttempts(String noTestAttempts) {
        this.noTestAttempts = noTestAttempts;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The productType
     */
    public String getProductType() {
        return productType;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param productType
     * The product_type
     */
    public void setProductType(String productType) {
        this.productType = productType;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The difficultyLevel
     */
    public String getDifficultyLevel() {
        return difficultyLevel;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param difficultyLevel
     * The difficulty_level
     */
    public void setDifficultyLevel(String difficultyLevel) {
        this.difficultyLevel = difficultyLevel;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The jignoCertified
     */
    public String getJignoCertified() {
        return jignoCertified;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param jignoCertified
     * The jigno_certified
     */
    public void setJignoCertified(String jignoCertified) {
        this.jignoCertified = jignoCertified;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The caRelated
     */
    public String getCaRelated() {
        return caRelated;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param caRelated
     * The ca_related
     */
    public void setCaRelated(String caRelated) {
        this.caRelated = caRelated;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The description
     */
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param description
     * The description
     */
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The shortDescription
     */
    public String getShortDescription() {
        return shortDescription;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param shortDescription
     * The short_description
     */
    public void setShortDescription(String shortDescription) {
        this.shortDescription = shortDescription;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The metaKeyword
     */
    public String getMetaKeyword() {
        return metaKeyword;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param metaKeyword
     * The meta_keyword
     */
    public void setMetaKeyword(String metaKeyword) {
        this.metaKeyword = metaKeyword;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The regularPriceWithTax
     */
    public Integer getRegularPriceWithTax() {
        return regularPriceWithTax;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param regularPriceWithTax
     * The regular_price_with_tax
     */
    public void setRegularPriceWithTax(Integer regularPriceWithTax) {
        this.regularPriceWithTax = regularPriceWithTax;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The regularPriceWithoutTax
     */
    public Integer getRegularPriceWithoutTax() {
        return regularPriceWithoutTax;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param regularPriceWithoutTax
     * The regular_price_without_tax
     */
    public void setRegularPriceWithoutTax(Integer regularPriceWithoutTax) {
        this.regularPriceWithoutTax = regularPriceWithoutTax;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The finalPriceWithTax
     */
    public Integer getFinalPriceWithTax() {
        return finalPriceWithTax;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param finalPriceWithTax
     * The final_price_with_tax
     */
    public void setFinalPriceWithTax(Integer finalPriceWithTax) {
        this.finalPriceWithTax = finalPriceWithTax;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The finalPriceWithoutTax
     */
    public Integer getFinalPriceWithoutTax() {
        return finalPriceWithoutTax;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param finalPriceWithoutTax
     * The final_price_without_tax
     */
    public void setFinalPriceWithoutTax(Integer finalPriceWithoutTax) {
        this.finalPriceWithoutTax = finalPriceWithoutTax;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The isSaleable
     */
    public Boolean getIsSaleable() {
        return isSaleable;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param isSaleable
     * The is_saleable
     */
    public void setIsSaleable(Boolean isSaleable) {
        this.isSaleable = isSaleable;
    }


}
```

}

Just Copy and Paste & rename it..
After that you can access that using get & set method...
Appreciation are welcome...

Comment: Hi... I tried the the above code... what if the products are dynamic... the total number of products keep on changing