# JSON Array on Objects to List of String

Tags: java, json, gson

I have the following JSON

```
[{
    "rowId": "03 EUR10580000"
}, {
    "rowId": "03 EUR10900001"
}, {
    "rowId": "03 EUR1053RUD*"
}, {
    "rowId": "033331"
}]
```

and I would like to convert it to a List of String with only the values of the rowId, so in this case like

```
"03 EUR10580000"
"03 EUR10900001"
"03 EUR1053RUD*"
"033331"
```

I did it with Gson fromJson but in return I get a List of LinkedTreeMap and when I do a loop in fails. I would like instead a simple List of String.

Comment: What fails? Can you show us the code you are using for the iteration? You can easily use the `values()` method of the `LinkedTreeMap`, which returns a `Collection`. Or you could iterate over the entries, map these to the values and collect them (using, e.g., lamba).

Comment: Please post the code of what you are doing with Gson. With jackson, this is really straightforward and I am certain it must be so with Gson as well.

Answer (score 3):

Well, your string is not a json of "list of string". It contains the list of objects. so what you can do is create a class with rowID as a string property.

class Data

- rowID (type string)

Then you can use Gson to parse this JSON string to List< Data > as used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688099/converting-json-to-java)

or you have to prepare a new json parser manually.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to parse your string quickly using `Gson`, you can simply create the builder and use the "default" `List` and `Map` instances used to represent your `JSON` in Java. If you want to be more type-safe, or you want to use the parsed instances in a "larger" project, I'd suggest to create a POJO as described in the other answers.

```
final GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();

// you may want to configure the builder

final Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

/*
 * The following only works if you are sure that your JSON looks
 * as described, otherwise List<Object> may be better and a validation,
 * within the iteration.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") 
final List<Map<String, String>> list = gson.fromJson("[{ ... }]", List.class);

final List<String> stringList = list.stream()
            .map(m -> m.get("rowId"))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(stringList);
```

Comment: You could use a `TypeToken` with your List like `final Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<YourObject>>(){}.getType();` to make sure you have the correct objects in your list and/or `builder.enableComplexMapKeySerialization().create();`

Answer (score 1):

Write a POJO class as

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class RootObject {

    @SerializedName("rowId")
    @Expose
    private String rowId;

    public String getRowId() {
        return rowId;
    }

    public void setRowId(String rowId) {
        this.rowId = rowId;
    }

}
```

Then just create `List<RootObject>`and get the values from the POJO.

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
String str = "[{\"rowId\":\"03 EUR10580000\"},{\"rowId\":\"03 EUR10900001\"},{\"rowId\":\"03 EUR1053RUD*\"},{\"rowId\":\"033331\"}]"
```

You can do something like this (no need of any external library like gson):

```
str = str.replace("{\"rowId\":\"","").replace("\"}","").replace("[","").replace("]","");
List<String> rowIDs = str.split(",");
```

If the string is formatted JSON, you can also `trim()` each of strings in `rowIDs`

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse json string as `JsonArray`. Then iterate over `JsonArray` instance and add each json element to list `ls`. Follwoing code sinppet is the solution :

```
    List<String> ls = new ArrayList<String>();
    String json = "[{\"rowId\":\"03 EUR10580000\"},{\"rowId\":\"03 EUR10900001\"},{\"rowId\":\"03 EUR1053RUD*\"},{\"rowId\":\"033331\"}]";
    JsonArray ja = new JsonParser().parse(json).getAsJsonArray();

    for(int i = 0; i < ja.size(); i++) {
       ls.add(ja.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("rowId").toString());
    }
    for(String rowId : ls) {
       System.out.println(rowId);
    }
    /* output : 
    "03 EUR10580000"
    "03 EUR10900001"
    "03 EUR1053RUD*"
    "033331" */
```