# GSON issue parsing a JSON array

Tags: json, gson

Here is my problem. I am getting a stacktrace trying to deserialize this json into a string array. Here is my json

```
[{"productId":"primary_savings","productName":"Primary Savings - Required Membership Account","productAmount":"0","isForFunding":"true"}]
```

Here is my code

```
    List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList(gson.fromJson(array1, String[].class));
```

and here is my stacktrace

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null
at com.google.gson.JsonElement.getAsString(JsonElement.java:184)
at com.google.gson.DefaultTypeAdapters$StringTypeAdapter.deserialize(DefaultTypeAdapters.java:968)
at com.google.gson.DefaultTypeAdapters$StringTypeAdapter.deserialize(DefaultTypeAdapters.java:960)
at com.google.gson.JsonDeserializerExceptionWrapper.deserialize(JsonDeserializerExceptionWrapper.java:51)
at com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationVisitor.invokeCustomDeserializer(JsonDeserializationVisitor.java:92)
at com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationVisitor.visitUsingCustomHandler(JsonDeserializationVisitor.java:80)
at com.google.gson.ObjectNavigator.accept(ObjectNavigator.java:101)
at com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationVisitor.visitChild(JsonDeserializationVisitor.java:110)
at com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationVisitor.visitChildAsObject(JsonDeserializationVisitor.java:99)
at com.google.gson.JsonArrayDeserializationVisitor.visitArray(JsonArrayDeserializationVisitor.java:70)
at com.google.gson.ObjectNavigator.accept(ObjectNavigator.java:112)
at com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContextDefault.fromJsonArray(JsonDeserializationContextDefault.java:67)
at com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContextDefault.deserialize(JsonDeserializationContextDefault.java:52)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:551)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:498)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:467)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:417)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:389)
at com.msp.acct.util.UnstructuredVarsUtil.mergeJsonArrays(UnstructuredVarsUtil.java:178)
at com.msp.acct.util.UnstructuredVarsUtil.mergeJsonObjects(UnstructuredVarsUtil.java:105)
at com.msp.acct.util.UnstructuredVarsUtil.mergeJsonObjects(UnstructuredVarsUtil.java:77)
at com.msp.acct.data.Persist.updateApplicantUnstructuredVars(Persist.java:1628)
at com.msp.acct.risk.dynamic.integrations.lending360.Lending360.appendPropertyToUnstructuredVars(Lending360.java:817)
at com.msp.acct.risk.dynamic.integrations.lending360.Lending360.checkExistingMember(Lending360.java:168)
at com.msp.acct.risk.dynamic.DynamicRiskEngine.checkExistingMember(DynamicRiskEngine.java:302)
at com.msp.acct.svc.ApplicantController.checkExistingMember(ApplicantController.java:360)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:747)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:676)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:301)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.DigestAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(DigestAuthenticationFilter.java:115)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.msp.acct.svc.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:83)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:676)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:74)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1015)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:652)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1575)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1533)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

What am I doing wrong here? I've seen other stackoverflow issues but none of them seem to resolve my issue.

Please assist

Comment: did you check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42132081/json-array-on-objects-to-list-of-string/42162906#42162906

Comment: Why do you need it to be deserialized to a list of strings?

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that the input is not an array of strings: it is an array containing one object that has string values. You have to iteratively extract the strings or create a class to map the object to, something like:

```
class Product {
  String productName;
  String productId;
  String productAmount;
  String isForFunding;
}
```

and then

```
Product[] product = gson.fromJson(array1, Product[].class)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use type as below :

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<String>>() {}.getType();
List<String> yourList = gson.fromJson(array1, listType);
```

[GSON API documentation](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md)

Comment: This didn't fix the issue.