# Having trouble creating a DTO class for the following JSON

Tags: java, arrays, json, arraylist, jackson

I am trying to create Dto class in Java for a json which is similar to this.

```
    {
    "abcList":[
        {
            "keyA":"valA",
            "lstB":[{
                "keyC":"valC"
            },{
                "keyC":"valC1"
            }]
        },{
            "keyA":"valA",
            "lstB":{
                "keyC":"valC2"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Is the Json even valid? Inside the list abcList, the first object has a list "lstB" and in the second object, the field "lstB" is not a list.

If the json is valid, how would I create the corresponding Java Classes?
This does not work.

```
class TopObject{
        List<ABC> abcList;


    }
    class ABC{
        public String keyA;
        public List<B> lstB;
    }
    class B{
        public String keyC;
    }
```

I mean I can parse it successfully with gson, iterating through every element of the json with a code like below,

```
if(lstB.isJsonArray()){
                System.out.println("lstb is array");
                List<B> arLstB = parseBArray(lstB);
                abc.setLstB(arLstB);
            }else{
                System.out.println("lstb is not array");
                B b = parseB(lstB);
                abc.addB(b);
            }
```

but the original json is very large and i will end up writing the iterating logic for days. I want a solution where I can annotate it properly and do the mapping in one shot like this.

```
gson.fromJson(jsonInString, TopObject.class);
```

Comment: jsonlint.com to validate your json

Comment: What is the correct DTO corresponding to this Json?

Comment: Your JSON-String is absolutely valid. Have a look at this article. I guess you'll find the answer needed in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688099/converting-json-to-java

Comment: Unfortunately that is a different case then mine and did not help.