# how to convert json data to java object and how to separate json data fields

Tags: java, json, rest

I am consuming data from url and stored in "output" string. 
How to convert that into java object and separate fields ?
Here is my code :

```
Client client = Client.create();
WebResource webResource = client
  .resource(url);
String name = "xxx";
String password = "xxx";
String authString = name + ":" + password;
String authStringEnc = new BASE64Encoder().encode(authString
  .getBytes());
//System.out.println("Base64 encoded auth string: " + authStringEnc);
ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json")
  .header("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc)
  .get(ClientResponse.class);
String output = response.getEntity(String.class);


System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
System.out.println(output);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting JSON to Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688099/converting-json-to-java)

Answer (score 0):

you can use [gson](https://github.com/google/gson) for this. import gson to your project.

```
    import java.lang.reflect.Type;
    import com.google.gson.Gson;
    import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

    //..
    //you can get the output here
    //String output = response.getEntity(String.class);

    Type listType = new TypeToken<FooObject>(){}.getType();
    FooObject fooObject =new Gson().fromJson(output, listType);
```

Comment: Type listType = new TypeToken<Student>(){}.getType();
      Student student =new Gson().fromJson(output, listType);

  
      System.out.println(student);     o/p :Student [college_name=null, college_id=0]
its showing like this .i want to get   particular column(college_name) values .can you please tell me the solution

Comment: yeap, that is right.  please check this [example](http://www.makeinjava.com/serialize-convert-list-objects-to-from-json-java-gson-example/) and you can modify type as object or collections.

Comment: i want that json object to store into data base .how can i send that json data to db.   iam getting o/p like this:({"counts":[{"college_name":"kit", hyd","college_id":777}...............................i created table in db.i want to store these json data into that table .

Comment: i am getting the data from client .so i want to add directly that data into db table .how cani convert thjat json data into java object and how can i save into particular columns of the table.

Comment: ok. i know what are you trying to do it. can you post the json data that comes to **output**. You just need to modify your object to catch json data

Comment: i found the right link that you need [link](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/) @Saideep

Comment: {"counts":[{"college_name":"Gii, Kakina","college_id":38},{"college_name":"GPT, Draksham","college_id":26}...............................i am getting the json data like this

Comment: i want to store that json data into db table