# How to convert a json string to an object

Tags: java, json

here is my pojo

```
public class Data{
 List<Object> objects;
 String owneruid;
}
```

if the out put is pure json like this

```
{"object":[{"p1":100,"p2":"name","p3":"sfa0","p4":300}],"owneruid":"owneruid"}
```

then iam able to convert with no worries but
here is my output

```
{  
  "object":"[{\"p1\":32,\"p3\":470,\"p3\":\"213\",\"p4\":\"name\"}]",
  "owneruid":"6697729776330393738"
}
```

im converting a json string to string because to store in my db as it does not accept json so when i query returns like above so every time i need to fetch the value and convert it to json object and put it in list and display. can you suggest me a better approach.

And when i try to convert a list of custom classes to json using GSON

```
ArrayList<Object> list=new ArrayList<>();
    Object object=new Object();
    object.setP1(3);
    object.setP2(4);
    list.add(object);
    
    Gson gson=new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(list);

 Required:
{"object":[{"p1":100,"p2":"name","p2":"sfa0","p4":300}],"owneruid":"owneruid"}
```

buts it ends like this

```
{"object":"[{\"p1\":313,\"p2\":470,\"p3\":\"1521739327417\",\"p4\":\"name\"}]","owneruid":"6697729776330393738"}
```

Comment: Use `Jackson` framework

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1688182/10447201

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting JSON data to Java object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688099/converting-json-data-to-java-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use any `json` frameworks. E.g. `Jackson` or `Gson`. As alternative you could do smth. like this. Just evaluate *JavaScript*.

```
public static void main(String... args) throws ScriptException {
    ScriptEngine js = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("javascript");
    Object obj = js.eval("[{\"width\":313,\"height\":470,\"mediauid\":\"1521739327417\",\"mediatype\":\"image\"}]");
    // res is either List<Object> or Map<String, Object> 
    Object res = convertIntoJavaObject(obj);
}

private static Object convertIntoJavaObject(Object obj) {
    if (!(obj instanceof ScriptObjectMirror))
        return obj;

    ScriptObjectMirror mirror = (ScriptObjectMirror)obj;

    if (mirror.isArray())
        return mirror.entrySet().stream()
                     .map(entry -> convertIntoJavaObject(entry.getValue()))
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());

    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    mirror.entrySet().forEach((key, value) -> map.put(key, convertIntoJavaObject(value)));

    return map;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code snippet as it seems fit for your case.
`ObjectMapper` can be found with Jackson framework. `inputJson` is the JSON string you have mentioned.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Object mediaMetaDataObj = mapper.readValue( inputJson, Object.class );
```

Hope this helps.