# Access the link and save the json variable you checked

Tags: java, json, oracle

[Data stored in oracledb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C41Aa.png)

Files stored in oracledb can be inquired to http://220.81.195.81:4000/sleep (server opened using nodejs).
You can look up like a picture.

Can I save the json format key,value as a variable for Java application?
I need some advice.

Comment: You can use Gson libraries to convert your json to Java objects with similar field names as json keys

Comment: Yes, Java allows your to map json on classes/objects. You can use ObjectMapper by Jackson to map Json on your Java objects.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting JSON data to Java object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688099/converting-json-data-to-java-object)