# java - Splitting JSON string into JSON strings in Java

Tags: java, json

I have below json string

```
{
   "folderId":1,
   "parentIds":{},
   "folderName":null,
   "hiddenFlag":true,
   "autoExecute":false,
   "updatedDate":"2020-10-15T11:40:55.000Z",
   "widgetItems":[
      {
         "width":4,
         "property":{
            "name":"GRID",
            "widgetdef":{
               "id":"91209e5a-6468-4912-b35a-ebfe84ac867e",
               "name":"GRID",
               "Title":{
                  "type":"TEXT",
                  "value":""
               },
               "dimCount":0,
               "reportTO":{
                  "source":{
                     "sourceId":388
                  },
                  "columns":[
                     {
                        "id":null,
                        "function":"SUM",
                        "operationErrorCode":0,
                        "totalAllUsingFunction":"Auto"
                     },
                     {
                        "id":null,
                        "function":"SUM",
                        "operationErrorCode":0,
                        "totalAllUsingFunction":"Auto"
                     }
                  ],
                  "columnSummaryType":0,
                  "drilldownDefaultDimension":{
                     
                  }
               },
               "splitBar":{
                  "value":true
               },
               "isExistingDashboard":true,
               "dimensionColumnCount":0
            }
         }
      }
   ],
   "dashboardName":"Second Dashboard",
   "dashboardType":1,
   "parentFolderId":1,
   "dashboardId":90208
}
```

**Am expecting output below json after split.**.I want to split `reportTO` object

```
{
    "source": {
        "sourceId": 388
    },
    "columns": [{
            "id": null,
            "function": "SUM",
            "operationErrorCode": 0,
            "totalAllUsingFunction": "Auto"
        },
        {
            "id": null,
            "function": "SUM",
            "operationErrorCode": 0,
            "totalAllUsingFunction": "Auto"
        }
    ],
    "columnSummaryType": 0,
    "drilldownDefaultDimension": {}
}
```

Comment: So what is your attempt? I'd serialize your JSON string to an object and then just grep the reportTO object.

Comment: @Milgo i am new to json, I could not able to think solution. Can you post as answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting JSON data to Java object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688099/converting-json-data-to-java-object)

Comment: @Milgo I want json output as expected result. I don't want Java Object. I have shown expected output in above question.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: @Dan posted an answer see if thats what u want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  {
    String rootJson = " {\r\n" + 
            "  \"folderId\": 1,\r\n" + 
            "  \"parentIds\": {},\r\n" + 
            "  \"folderName\": null,\r\n" + 
            "  \"hiddenFlag\": true,\r\n" + 
            "  \"autoExecute\": false,\r\n" + 
            "  \"updatedDate\": \"2020-10-15T11:40:55.000Z\",\r\n" + 
            "  \"widgetItems\": [\r\n" + 
            "    { \r\n" + 
            "      \"width\": 4,\r\n" + 
            "      \"property\": {\r\n" + 
            "        \"name\": \"GRID\",\r\n" + 
            "        \"widgetdef\": {\r\n" + 
            "          \"id\": \"91209e5a-6468-4912-b35a-ebfe84ac867e\",\r\n" + 
            "          \"name\": \"GRID\",\r\n" + 
            "          \"Title\": {\r\n" + 
            "            \"type\": \"TEXT\",\r\n" + 
            "            \"value\": \"\"\r\n" + 
            "          }, \r\n" + 
            "          \"dimCount\": 0,\r\n" + 
            "          \"reportTO\": {\r\n" + 
            "            \"source\": {\r\n" + 
            "              \"sourceId\": 388\r\n" + 
            "            },\r\n" + 
            "            \"columns\": [\r\n" + 
            "              {\r\n" + 
            "                \"id\": null, \r\n" + 
            "                \"function\": \"SUM\", \r\n" + 
            "                \"operationErrorCode\": 0,\r\n" + 
            "                \"totalAllUsingFunction\": \"Auto\"\r\n" + 
            "              },\r\n" + 
            "              {\r\n" + 
            "                \"id\": null, \r\n" + 
            "                \"function\": \"SUM\", \r\n" + 
            "                \"operationErrorCode\": 0,\r\n" + 
            "                \"totalAllUsingFunction\": \"Auto\"\r\n" + 
            "              } \r\n" + 
            "            ],  \r\n" + 
            "            \"columnSummaryType\": 0,\r\n" + 
            "            \"drilldownDefaultDimension\": {}\r\n" + 
            "          },\r\n" + 
            "          \"splitBar\": {\r\n" + 
            "            \"value\": true\r\n" + 
            "          },  \r\n" + 
            "          \"isExistingDashboard\": true,\r\n" + 
            "          \"dimensionColumnCount\": 0\r\n" + 
            "        }\r\n" + 
            "      }\r\n" + 
            "    } \r\n" + 
            "  ],\r\n" + 
            "  \"dashboardName\": \"Second Dashboard\",\r\n" + 
            "  \"dashboardType\": 1,\r\n" + 
            "  \"parentFolderId\": 1,  \r\n" + 
            "  \"dashboardId\": 90208\r\n" + 
            "}";
    
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(rootJson);
    JSONObject reportJson = jsonObject.getJSONArray("widgetItems").getJSONObject(0).
                                            getJSONObject("property").
                                                  getJSONObject("widgetdef").
                                                       getJSONObject("reportTO");
    System.out.println(reportJson);
    
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{
   "drilldownDefaultDimension":{
      
   },
   "columns":[
      {
         "function":"SUM",
         "totalAllUsingFunction":"Auto",
         "id":null,
         "operationErrorCode":0
      },
      {
         "function":"SUM",
         "totalAllUsingFunction":"Auto",
         "id":null,
         "operationErrorCode":0
      }
   ],
   "columnSummaryType":0,
   "source":{
      "sourceId":388
   }
}
```